# How to manipulate strings in prolog?

Tags: string, prolog

I have this fact in my base
fact("name","surname","123").
if i simply write this question:
fact(X,_,_). For X I get some unidentified output. 
How can I retrieve any of this values, or how to get this output?
?-fact(X,_,_).
output: name.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Try fact(X,_,_).  (last two arguments are underscores)

Answer (score 3):

In SWI-Prolog you can use `string_to_atom/2`:

```
?- assert(fact("name", "surname", "123")).
true.

?- fact(Tmp, _, _), string_to_atom(Tmp, X).
Tmp = [110, 97, 109, 101],
X = name.
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Prolog are enclosed within single quotes. When you use double quotes it means that you want the list of character codes.

```
?- is_list('abc').
false.

?- is_list("abc").
true.

?- write("abc").
[97,98,99]
true.

?- write('abc').
abc
true.
```

Comment: ?- string('abc').
false. (in SWI-Prolog)

Comment: Strings in Prolog are typically enclosed within *double* quotes, which are syntactic sugar for a list of character codes. **Atoms** in Prolog are  enclosed within single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
| ?- assert(fact("name", "surname", "123")).
yes
| ?- fact(X,_,_).
X = [110,97,109,101];
| ?- fact(_X,_,_),name(Y,_X).
Y = name;
```