# What is the difference between ' and " in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, double-quotes, dcg, iso-prolog

I am new to Prolog and noticed that ' and " give different behavior, but am curious as to why.  Specifically, when loading a file, `?- ['test1.pl'].` works, while `?- ["test1.pl"].` doesn't.

Comment: In SWI-Prolog 7 and later, both work and mean the same. As someone will surely point out, this is not ISO-Prolog compliant behaviour. And please, un-accept the currently accepted answer because it is incorrect.

Comment: @Boris: with `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, atom)` both queries are the same as is exemplified by default in IF/Prolog. Even SWI7 [can do better](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/SWI7_and_ISO#strings_less_non_conforming), although as a whole SWI7 is not conforming.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Single quoted items are always atoms.

The meaning of double quotes depends on the Prolog flag `double_quotes`:

---

**`atom`** —
with this value `"a" = a`. Nowadays, this is rarely used. But you will find Prolog books where `["abc.pl"]` is written.

---

**`codes`** —
a list of character codes. In older systems this is frequently the default, but it leads to very unreadable answers like

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,codes).
   true.
?- phrase(("Ja tvoi ",("sluga"|"rabotnik"),"!"), Satz).
   Satz = [74,97,32,116,118,111,105,32,115,108,117,103,97,33]
;  Satz = [74,97,32,116,118,111,105,32,114,97,98,111,116,110,105,107,33].
```

Even worse, if you use characters beyond ASCII:

```
?- phrase(("Я твой ",("слуга"|"работник"),"!"), Satz).
   Satz = [1071,32,1090,1074,1086,1081,32,1089,1083,1091,1075,1072,33]
;  Satz = [1071,32,1090,1074,1086,1081,32,1088,1072,1073,1086,1090,1085,1080,1082,33].
```

---

**`chars`**
— a list of one-char atoms. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36645725/772868) for more about it.

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).
   true.
?- phrase(("Ja tvoi ",("sluga"|"rabotnik"),"!"), Satz).
   Satz = ['J',a,' ',t,v,o,i,' ',s,l,u,g,a,!]
;  Satz = ['J',a,' ',t,v,o,i,' ',r,a,b,o,t,n,i,k,!].
?- phrase(("Я твой ",("слуга"|"работник"),"!"), Satz).
   Satz = ['Я',' ',т,в,о,й,' ',с,л,у,г,а,!]
;  Satz = ['Я',' ',т,в,о,й,' ',р,а,б,о,т,н,и,к,!].
```

This notation gives more readable answers and is the default in [Scryer](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog),
[Tau](http://tau-prolog.org),
[Trealla](https://github.com/infradig/trealla),
and
[Ichiban](https://github.com/ichiban/prolog).
Scryer and Trealla display them even more compactly with the double quote notation for printing any list of one-char atoms. For [SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/double_quotes.pl) and [SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/double_quotes.pl) this can be emulated with the following library.

```
?- use_module(library(double_quotes)).
   true.
?- phrase(("Ja tvoi ",("sluga"|"rabotnik"),"!"), Satz).
   Satz = "Ja tvoi sluga!"
;  Satz = "Ja tvoi rabotnik!".
?- phrase(("Я твой ",("слуга"|"работник"),"!"), Satz).
   Satz = "Я твой слуга!"
;  Satz = "Я твой работник!".
```

If you have difficulties installing `double_quotes.pl` as a library, simply put it into the directory of your other Prolog files and say: `use_module(double_quotes).`

Comment: Thanks for expanding on the answer above.

Comment: @astay13 This answer is correct, while the other is not. It does not "expand" on the other answer.

Answer (score 10):

Strings in Prolog are written in single quotes. Terms written in double quotes are immediately converted to a list of character codes.

```
?- write('sdf').
sdf
true.

?- write("sdf").
[115, 100, 102]
true.
```

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391435/how-to-manipulate-strings-in-prolog)

Comment: *Atoms* in Prolog are enclosed within single quotes.

Comment: Maybe a minor qualification: Atoms are usually just written down. Only if they would otherwise be mistaken for something else (like for example a variable) do you enclose them in single quotes. You can optionally do it in every case, only it's pointless.

Comment: This answer is misleading at best. Sadly, it is the accepted answer.