# what is the syntax for char* in prolog

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

I want to know the syntax for char* in prolog which i want to use for a list of a characters. I have used list=integer* for a list of integers but i dont know sysntax for characters list in prolog.

Comment: For ISO Prolog, please look at [this answer][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264699/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-prolog/8269897#8269897

Comment: In Prolog there is not such thing as pointers or typed variables, so there is nothing like "char *" in prolog. But, if you tell us what you want to do at a higher level we will be able to show you how to do it in Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

In SWI-Prolog, you must use _string_to_list /2 to create strings :

> ?- A = "ABCD".
>      A = [65,66,67,68].
>
> ?- string_to_list(A, "ABCD").
>  A = "ABCD".

Comment: OP is using Turbo Prolog. You can tell because he defines a ´list=integer*´ which is Turbo Prolog specific

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Turbo Prolog.
In that case, there is already a predefined domain **string** used for strings.

Here goes a usage example:

```
predicates
  test(string, string).

clauses
test(X, Z):- concat("Hello ", X, Z).
```

Sample output:

```
Goal: test("World",Z).
Z=Hello World
1 Solution
```