# Handling prolog context free grammar

Tags: prolog, context-free-grammar, dcg, prolog-dif

Given a CFG

```
S --> a S b | c | d
```

I wanna write a predicate like, **grammar('S', sentence)** which generates all possible

```
sentences like
sentence=acb,
sentence=acd,
sentence=c,
sentence=ab......................
```

Using *left most derivation*, if the encountered symbol is *terminal* it should print out that terminal, and if the encountered symbol is *non terminal* **'S'**, it should backtrack and substitute and one of the grammar **a S b or c or d** and repeat the process.

I dont want any code...just help me with some tips how to start with

Comment: SO is not a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: You don't have to "write the code" you can just give him some pointers

Comment: @mah i'm not expecting any code...but a few tips or any links with some good examples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's use DCGs to encode your grammar literally!

```
s --> [a], s, [b] | [c] | [d].

?- phrase(s,Xs).
   loops. % ERROR: Out of local stack
```

Seems that this query does not terminate.  I.e. Prolog's very simple execution strategy did not find a solution.  On the other hand, think of it: Your grammar describes an infinite set of sentences. If you are enumerating an infinite set it is easy to start "at the wrong end". That's what Prolog actually does here.

But things are not that bad at all.  What about enumerating all sentences of a fixed length. I will try 5:

```
?- length(Xs,5), phrase(s,Xs).
   Xs = "aacbb"
;  Xs = "aadbb"
;  false.
```

In this case, all sentences are found and Prolog even assures us that there are no further sentences.

```
?- length(Xs,4), phrase(s,Xs).
   false.
```

There are no sentences of length 4.

We can now enumerate *all* sentences, **by length**.

```
?- length(Xs,N), phrase(s,Xs).
   Xs = "c", N = 1
;  Xs = "d", N = 1
;  Xs = "acb", N = 3
;  Xs = "adb", N = 3
;  Xs = "aacbb", N = 5
;  Xs = "aadbb", N = 5
;  Xs = "aaacbbb", N = 7
; ... .
```

What kind of derivation did we use here? Honestly, I don't know and I don't care. What is important to know is when Prolog will terminate.  In this case, it will terminate, if the length is known.  And that is all we need to know to guarantee that we have a **fair enumeration** of the infinite set. Things are even slightly better: `s//0` will also terminate in cases where the length is not known like

```
?- Xs = [a,a,b|_], phrase(s,Xs).
   false.
?- Xs = [a,a,c|_], phrase(s,Xs).
   Xs = "aacbb"
;  false.
?- dif(X,Y), Xs = [X,Y|_], phrase(s,Xs).
   X = a, Y = c, Xs = "acb"
;  X = a, Y = d, Xs = "adb"
;  false.
```

Edit: I got some questions about the toplevel answers using `"acb"` for a list `[a,c,b]`: Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) for an explanation and to [`library(double_quotes)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/double_quotes.pl).