# Recursive Function with If-Else Statements in Prolog

Tags: if-statement, recursion, prolog, iso-prolog

I'm trying to write a recursive function in prolog that computes `R = (2*X + Y)^N` without using the exponent operator. I've written a recursive function with if-else statements and I get the error: `) or operator expected`. It looks to me like I have the syntax correct, but I must be missing something. The code is below.

```
expbar(R, X, Y, N) :-
    (X =:= Y =:= N =:= 0 -> 
        write("No two variables can equal 0 at the same time.");
        (N =:= 0 ->
            R is 2 * X + Y;
            R is (2 * X + Y) * expbar(R, X, Y, N-1)
        )
    ).
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the expression `2*X+Y` all the time. Why not calculate it **first** and then use that result for the actual computation? Maybe you missed here something in the problem statement?

Why do you want to exclude the case where `X`, `Y` and `N` are all 0? ... while you are not excluding the case of `N < 0`?

### Argument order

It is common in Prolog to put results **after** the corresponding input arguments. There are exceptions to this rule, `(is)/2` is the most common example, but it is written as an infix operator.

### Error signalling

For cases you cannot handle properly there are two options in Prolog. Either you silently fail or you issue a clean error. (There is a third – looping, which while not ideal is still better than succeeding.)  Currently, you write out a text and then you succeed. So you are assuming that someone will read your message. But frequently programs run unattended and the message is ignored.

Imagine I want to use your definition to prove that your definition is the question to *the* answer:

```
?- expbar(42, 0, 0, 0).
```

This is what I get in SWI after rewriting `X =:= Y =:= N =:= 0` to `X =:= 0, Y =:= 0, N =:= 0`.

```
?- expbar(42, 0, 0, 0).
[78,111,32,116,119,111,32,118,97,114,105,97,98,108,101,115,32,99,97,110,32,101,113,117,97,108,32,48,32,97,116,32,116,104,101,32,115,97,109,101,32,116,105,109,101,46]
true.
```

It says `true.`! And these numbers above are certainly some progress messages from such a highly complex calculation... So it is very easy to misread your message.  It would have been a bit easier if you would have used single quotes. [More about single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868). But even with a more readable message, it is easy to skip it.

The proper way to handle such a situation is by issuing an error:

```
    throw(error(Error_term,_More_info))
```

In this manner the computation is aborted and the error is handled by the toplevel (or the next place where a `catch/3` handles it). This lowers the chances that the error will be misinterpreted.

The `Error_term` should be ideally one of the existing error terms.
Here is the [complete list of errors in ISO Prolog](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/error_k#error_classes).
In your case it might an `evaluation_error(undefined)` similarly to the [definition of exponentiation](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#9.3.10).

Answer (score 0):

expbar is not a function. Correct is

```
expbar(R, X, Y, N) :-
(X =:= Y =:= N =:= 0 -> 
    write("No two variables can equal 0 at the same time.");
    (N =:= 0 ->
        R is 2 * X + Y;
        N1 is N - 1,
        expbar(R1, X, Y, N1)
        R is (2 * X + Y) * R1
    )
).
```

Comment: I implemented this code but am still getting the ") or operator expected" What is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: @aclark, please look at the other answers `X =:= Y =:= N =:= 0` is invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should have a syntax error on initial condition.
Adding to joel76 answer:

```
expbar(R, X, Y, N) :-
    (   ( X =:= 0, Y =:= 0 ; X =:= 0, N =:= 0 ; Y =:= 0, N =:= 0 )
    ->  write("No two variables can equal 0 at the same time.")
    ;   (   N =:= 0
        ->  R is 2 * X + Y
        ;   N1 is N - 1,
            expbar(R1, X, Y, N1),
            R is (2 * X + Y) * R1
        )
    ).
```

Comment: the value of `R` if `N =:= 0` would be `1` more than `2 * X + Y` I think. And the expression is calculable as long as `2 * X + Y` or N is different of `0`, the test cases might be too broad.