# prolog convert numbers into roman numerals

Tags: numbers, prolog, dcg, clpfd, roman-numerals

i have this code that converts integers into roman numerals 
i need to add a function that compares an integer with a roman numeral input and show if it's try or false, for example:
roman(v,5).
true

```
toroman(0).
toroman(N) :- N < 4, put("I"), M is N - 1, toroman(M).
toroman(N) :- N = 4, put("I"), put("V").
toroman(N) :- N = 5, put("V").
toroman(N) :- N < 9, put("V"), M is N - 5, toroman(M).
toroman(N) :- N = 9, put("I"), put("X").
toroman(N) :- N < 40, put("X"), M is N - 10, toroman(M).
toroman(N) :- N < 50, put("X"), put("L"), M is N - 40, toroman(M).
toroman(N) :- N < 90, put("L"), M is N - 50, toroman(M).
toroman(N) :- N < 100, put("X"), put("C"), M is N - 90, toroman(M).
toroman(N) :- N < 400, put("C"), M is N - 100, toroman(M).
toroman(N) :- N < 500, put("C"), put("D"), M is N - 400, toroman(M).
toroman(N) :- N < 900, put("D"), put("D"), M is N - 500, toroman(M).
toroman(N) :- N < 1000, put("C"), put("M"), M is N - 900, toroman(M).
toroman(N) :- N < 4000, put("M"), M is N - 1000, toroman(M).



roman(N) :- toroman(N).
```

Comment: Try `toroman(-1)`: You get `IVXXLXCCDCM`. That is the same value as `toroman(0+9)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to formulate the problem differently: Write a grammar ([dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)) to relate an integer and a list of characters denoting roman numerals. Here is a start:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

roman(0) --> "".
roman(N0) --> "I", { 1 #=< N0, N0 #=< 3, N1 #= N0-1}, roman(N1).
```

You can use it like so:

```
?- phrase(roman(3), L).
   L = "III"
;  false.
```

or

```
?- phrase(roman(N), "II").
   N = 2
;  false.
```

or, if you don't know what to ask, simply ask the most general question:

```
?- phrase(roman(N), L).
   N = 0, L = []
;  N = 1, L = "I"
;  N = 2, L = "II"
;  N = 3, L = "III"
;  false.
```

To get answers compactly like `L = "III"`, use `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).` See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) for more.

Comment: using CLP(FD) to express semantic on DCG seems really interesting!

Comment: @chac: CLP(FD) in SWI is really meant as a purer replacement for integer arithmetics.

Comment: it offers such high level constructs, it's much more than arithmetic, at least practically.

Comment: @chac: most CLP(FD) implementations have serious correctness and other restrictions which makes them unusable as a replacement.

Comment: Yes, it's great to have CLP(FD) in plain Prolog. Thanks Markus !!

Comment: This : http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Encode#Prolog may be interesting

Comment: @joel76: Thanks. What is very sad is that people do not understand that there are many nice shortcuts like `IIL` which I recently found in my library.

Comment: @joel76: I think the schema by false is better than that!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `toroman/1` procedure to something like `toroman/2` that returns the roman numeral instead of just printing it.

Then you would be able to easily compare a roman numeral with the result from calling `toroman/2` to the integer.

Note also that your current procedure will loop until getting a stack overflow if you backtrack for another solution. You should either guard each clause that recursively calls itself to recurse only if the parameter of the call is non-negative or add as the first clause  a check that fails safely, e.g.:

```
roman(N):- N < 0, !, fail.
```

After changing toroman/1 to return the roman literal you would get something like this (just modified a bit your code to return the literal as the second argument):

```
toroman(N, _):- N < 0, !, fail.
toroman(0, []).
toroman(N, ['I'|Roman]) :- N < 4, M is N - 1, toroman(M, Roman).
toroman(4, ['IV']).
toroman(5, ['V']).
toroman(N, ['V'|Roman]) :- N < 9, M is N - 5, toroman(M, Roman).
toroman(9, ['IX']).
toroman(N, ['X'|Roman]) :- N < 40, M is N - 10, toroman(M, Roman).
toroman(N, ['XL'|Roman]) :- N < 50, M is N - 40, toroman(M, Roman).
toroman(N, ['L'|Roman]) :- N < 90, M is N - 50, toroman(M, Roman).
toroman(N, ['XC'|Roman]) :- N < 100, M is N - 90, toroman(M, Roman).
toroman(N, ['C'|Roman]) :- N < 400, M is N - 100, toroman(M, Roman).
toroman(N, ['CD'|Roman]) :- N < 500, M is N - 400, toroman(M, Roman).
toroman(N, ['DD'|Roman]) :- N < 900, M is N - 500, toroman(M, Roman).
toroman(N, ['CM'|Roman]) :- N < 1000, M is N - 900, toroman(M, Roman).
toroman(N, ['M'|Roman]) :- N < 4000, M is N - 1000, toroman(M, Roman).

roman(N, R) :- toroman(N, L), atomic_list_concat(L, R).

roman(N) :- roman(N, R), write(R).
```

Then you could simply call `roman(N, R)` and test whether `R` unifies with your roman numeral of interest.

Comment: thanks that was really helpful. list is what i needed. i was trying to modify your code to get a result of true or false with a questions like : 
?- roman (5,V).
true.

?- roman(5,R).
R=V.

what should i change ?

Comment: You have to enclose the roman literal within single quotes (because ou want to use an atom, not a variable). So, for example you could ask ?- roman(5, 'V').

Comment: i got it just had to change all capital letter to small