# How do I test if a list contains two atoms next to each other in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, dcg, roman-numerals

I am trying to write a predicate in GNU Prolog that tests if a roman numeral, stored as a list of characters, is well formed. Namely, if the list contains [i, c], [i, m], or [x, m], it is invalid. For example, if I passed in [m, i, m], the output would be `no`.

How would I go about doing this? I am aware of the member/2 function; is there a way to use that to test if a list contains a sublist?

Answer (score 2):

Found a built-in sublist function that does exactly what I need:

```
sublist([i, m], [m, i, m]) ==> `true`
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use grammars ([dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)). And use

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

which permits you to write `"mcm"` in place of `[m,c,m]`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13269846/772868) for more.