# prolog program to check whether a given input is digit or uppercase or lowercase

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, iso-prolog

I have used the following logic for above program but it gives error showing `>=/2: Arithmetic: 'a/0' is not a function`. What should i do to correct the program?

```
digit(X):- X>=0,X<10,write('input is digit').
uppercase(X):- X>='A',X<'[',write('input is uppercase').
lowercase(X):- X>='a',X<'{',write('input is lowercase').
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to classify just the ASCII characters in ISO Prolog, you can do this in various ways:

**As characters** which are represented as atoms of length 1. To compare them you can use the general term comparison `(@>=)/2`, `(@>)/2` ... In your example, that would be:

```
digit_char(X) :- atom_length(X,1), X @>= '0', X @=< '9'.
...
```

**As character codes** which are plain integers representing the *collating sequence integer* (sounds impressive? Its just the ASCII-code).

```
digit_code(X) :- integer(X), X >= 0'0, X =< 0'9.
...
```

If you need to convert between both, there is `char_code/2`.

For Unicode, things are not yet generally available and agreed upon. In SWI, there is [`char_type/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/search?for=char_type/2&in=all&match=summary) and `code_type/2`. Beware, these things are still evolving...

For more about characters and codes, see
[What is the difference between ' and " in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264699/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-prolog/8269897#8269897)