# Standard way to see what phrase/3 translates?

Tags: prolog, dcg, gnu-prolog, iso-prolog

I am trying to dig into the GNU Prolog behaviour of:

```
test(X,I,O) :- phrase(X,I,O).
?- test(("a",!,"b"),"ab","").
```

Is there a standard way to see to what phrase/3 translates?

According to the ISO DCG proposal (*), there is the requirement
that we will have an expand_term/2. Now I can use this to check:

```
?- expand_term((foo --> "a", !, "b"),X).
X = (foo([97|A],B):-!,A=[98|B])
```

Does this tell me how phrase/3 is used in my test/3?

(*)
ISO/IEC DTR 13211–3:2006
Definite clause grammar rules
Klaus Daessler
November 20, 2012
http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dcgs/dcgsdin121120.pdf

Comment: Are you using a specific version of GNU?

Comment: I am interested in a solution for gprolog 1.4.1 and 1.4.2.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a standard way to see the what phrase/3 translates?

No. The meaning of `phrase/3` is defined, but the actual implementation behind is not accessible. There are several different ways, how `phrase/3` can be defined. It could be as simple as [in YAP](http://yap.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=yap/yap-6.3;a=blob;f=pl/grammar.yap;h=f532a6c0238cec9f9bc425d205e7a7648e8943ec;hb=9c42dfa26caec69285c25df681d0d06ecb8e61ad#l135):

```
phrase(P, S0, S) :-
        call(P, S0, S).
```

Or it could use `expand_term/2` (or something of that kind). That is:

```
phrase(P, S0, S) :-
   expand_term(( pseudont --> P ), ( pseudont(CS0, CS) :- Goal) )),
   S0 = CS0,
   S = CS,
   Goal.
```

It could execute the final unification after calling `Goal`:

```
phrase(P, S0, S) :-
   expand_term(( pseudont --> P ), ( pseudont(CS0, CS) :- Goal) )),
   S0 = CS0,
   Goal,
   S = CS.
```

And by that introduce the (implementation dependent) convention that the expanded predicates are always called with an uninstantiated and unaliased variable in the last argument which would permit tail-recursiveness in the presence of semicontext.

It is all up to the implementer.

> Does this tell me how phrase/3 is used in my test/3?

No, there is no way telling.

But then, why do you ask? Or, to rephrase:

> What effect could a differing but conforming implementation of `phrase/3` have?

### Resource consumption

This should be evident.  Consider `?- phrase([],Xs).` which does not create any term on the heap in YAP, but does so for the naive `expand_term`-expansion above. But then, resource consumption is out of scope of the current standards.

### Variable ordering

Consider the body of a rule `..., phrase([], Xs, Xs), ...` in YAP: `Xs` remains a local variable, whereas an `expand_term`-based phrase makes it global. In many implementations this would affect the relative order of variables. Now, the standard explicitly states in 7.2.1:

> If X and Y are variables which are not identical then
> X term_precedes Y shall be implementation dependent
> except that during the creation of a sorted list (7.1.6.5,
> 8.10.3.1 j) the ordering shall remain constant.

So this is again not a problem, but still this might be annoying.

### NSTO property

The Prolog standard (that is, part 1 ISO/IEC 13211-1) only defines execution if it is NSTO. That is, if all unifications happening during execution are NSTO — Not subject to occurs-check (see 7.3.3).

Now, consider your case: `phrase(("a",!,"b"), Xs, Ys)`. At first sight, this is equivalent to `phrase("ab", Xs, Ys)`.  But now consider assuming [`set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868)

```
?- Xs = [c|_], Xs = Ys, phrase(("a",!,"b"), Xs, Ys).
```

This query should fail, no doubt. But is it NSTO? Naively, we could assume that this can be replaced by:

```
?- Xs = [c|_], Xs = Ys, Xs = [a,b|Ys].
```

Which is tantamount to:

```
?- Xs = [c|_], Xs = [a,b|Xs].
```

Clearly, `Xs = [a,b|Xs]` alone is STO (Subject to occurs check). But also both together are STO! To understand this, consider the Herbrand algorithm in 7.3.2. In essence, it non-deterministically rewrites the equations "in any order". Here is one such derivation:

```
          Xs = [c|Zs], Xs = [a,b|Xs].
(7.3.2 f) Xs = [c|Zs], [c|Zs] = [a,b,c|Zs].
(7.3.2 d) Xs = [c|Zs], c = a, Zs = [b,c|Zs].
(7.3.2 g) failure (not unifiable, positive occurs-check)
```

Of course, this derivation is unusual. Usually, one would fail immediately in the presence of `c = a`, but the algorithm is non-deterministic in this respect. And a set of equations is NSTO only if all possible derivations do not lead to 7.3.2 g. To cite 7.3.3:

> A set of equations (or two terms) is "not subject to
> occurs-check" (NSTO) iff there exists no way to proceed
> through the steps of the Herbrand Algorithm such that
> 7.3.2 g happens.

### freeze/2 and when/2

These constructs might also be affected. While they are currently not covered by existing standard documents understanding potential impacts is still of relevance. Consider:

```
?- freeze(L, (X=1;X=2)), phrase(("a",!,"b"),L).
   L = [a,b], X = 1.
```

B, SICStus, SWI, YAP all produce this one answer. So the cut is significant.

---

In any case, thanks for asking – I understood the NSTO issue only while answering your question! This clearly has some impact in how the DCG translation is formulated.

Comment: No, I am not interested in NSTO issues here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the ISO DCG does not define a way to figure out what phrase/3 is using as an executed term, the only way to figure it out, is to consult the source code. It is found here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gprolog/

The phrase/3 predicate is defined in a file called expand.pl. Its definition uses '$dcg_trans_body'/4. We can check it:

```
GNU Prolog 1.4.2
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2012 Daniel Diaz
| ?- '$dcg_trans_body'(("a",!,"b"), In, Out1, Body).

Body = (!,A=[98|Out1])
In = [97|A]
```

So the first terminal is indeed merged into the In parameter, similar as in the
foo rule. Since this is done when phrase/3 is invoked, it shouldn't be a problem.