# Writing elements in prolog console

Tags: prolog, dcg

In prolog I have do to something like this:

```
    ************************
    *                      *
    *      ##########      *
    *      # button #      *
    *      ##########      *
    *                      *
    ************************
```

User gives the width and height of window (created with *), and coordinates, width, height and text of button (created by #). This "window" is written in prolog console. I don't have trouble with writing the window itself but I don't know how to do it with something in it. Can anyone help me, I don't mean writing it for me, but even small guidenes will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it with the help of a DCG as a clean grammar.

Here is a start. [More details, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868).

```
:- use_module(library(double_quotes)).
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).

newline --> "\n".

pre --> "# ".

post --> " #".

button -->
   pre,
   "button",
   post.
```

Now you can query it on the toplevel:

```
?- phrase(button, Xs).
   Xs = "# button #".
```

And you can print it out directly:

```
?- phrase(button, Xs), atom_chars(A, Xs), write(A).
```

Comment: phrase and atom_chars seems promising but the thing you did with button is not so simple. I don't know the width of button, it not always will look like this # button #

Comment: @lukasz128: This is a starting point only - as you demanded it

Comment: I know. But anyway I can't figure out how to do this. I'm trying to built a list for each line, but I've got no results.

Answer (score 0):

Look at format/2,  which works like printf in C++