# Why it can not be calculated as an integer?

Tags: prolog

So basically in `GNU-Prolog`, I have some code like this:

```
....
( integer(X) -> write("TRUE"), nl
  ;             write("FALSE"), nl
),
write(X /\ 0xff), nl.
```

And according to the output, I am sure that `X` is and integer..

But what I am confused is that, the second output is something like this:

```
435321 /\ 0xff
```

and what I am expecting is the **value** of `435321 /\ 0xff`...

What is wrong here? Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: Please note that write("TRUE"). produces (by default) [84,82,85,69] in GNU. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264699/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-prolog/8269897#8269897

Comment: @false Hi, false, Yes, I know it, I just want to make a simple example..:)

Comment: If you say `write('TRUE')` instead, everything would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog evaluates arithmetic expressions only in some specific situations (`is`, arithmetic comparisons, etc...)

You should do this: `Result is X /\ 0xff, write(Result)`.