# SWI Prolog escape quotes

Tags: string, prolog, swi-prolog

I need to put " " around a String in prolog.
I get the input from another program and as it looks I can't escape the " in this program, so i have to add the " in prolog otherwise the prolog statement doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can also consider using `atom_string/2`, e.g.: `?- atom_string(monkey, String).` results in `String = "monkey"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I got the solution. I had the completly wrong approach. It was a change from SWI6 to SWI7. I installed SWI6.6 again and now it runs perfectly.

Comment: @Tim: There are some specific non ISO changes in SWI7 with respect to double quoted lists.

Comment: @false: exactly. I had than had this problem:
**?- writeq('.'(a,[])).
ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `a'**

Some information about the problem can be found her: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/SWI7_and_ISO

Comment: Your question does not actually describe the problem. Some code would be highly useful.

Comment: @Tim I do not understand how switching to SWI6 has solved your problem. SWI6 does not support strings at all, so you would also not be able to put double quotes around them...

Comment: @WouterBeek: It all depends on what you mean by string. ISO supports the double quoted notation `"a"` ([see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868)). And traditionally a list of character codes is a string.

Answer (score 2):

For a discussion of [strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39922411/502187) see here, they are SWI-Prolog specific but use the same escape rules as atoms. There are many ways to enter quotes into an atom in a Prolog text:

1) Doubling them. So for example 'can''t be' is an atom,
   with a single quote as the fourth character, and no other
   single quotes in it.

2) Escaping them, with the backslash. So for example 
   'can\'t be' is the same atom as 'can''t be'.

3) Character coding them, using octal code and a closing back slash. 
   So for example 'can\47\t be' is the same atom as 'can''t be'.

4) Character coding them, using hex code and a closing back slash. 
   So for example 'can\x27\t be' is the same atom as 'can''t be'.

The above possibilities are all defined in the ISO standard. A
Prolog implementation might define further possibilities.

Bye

P.S.: Here is an example run in SWI-Prolog, using a different
example character. In the first example query below, you don't 
need doubling, doubling can only be done for the surrounding quote.

The last example query below shows a SWI-Prolog specific syntax 
which is not found in the ISO standard, namely using a backslash 
u with a fixed width hex code:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.1.33)
Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam

?- X = 'she said "bye"'.
X = 'she said "bye"'.

?- X = 'she said \"bye\"'.
X = 'she said "bye"'.

?- X = 'she said \42\bye\42\'.
X = 'she said "bye"'.

?- X = 'she said \x22\bye\x22\'.
X = 'she said "bye"'.

?- X = 'she said \u0022bye\u0022'.
X = 'she said "bye"'.
```

Comment: Which SWI-Prolog did you use above? And if 7.x, did you use the command line option "--traditional"?

Comment: Why do you ask? Is something wrong in my answer? The only non-ISO is the \uXXXX syntax. I don't know whether it existed already in SWI6 or is only present in SWI7.

Comment: I was just being curious!

Comment: I am not sure whether SWI-Prolog has additionally \UXXXXXXXX, oh hell it does: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=unicodesyntax .