# Prolog: how to check if a word is contained in a list

Tags: list, prolog

Let's say I have these rules:

```
rule([a,t,e],[8]).
rule([f,o,r],[4]).
```

I have to check if in a word (for example `[f,o,r,t,r,e,s,s]`) there is a word that is in the list of rules and if there is to remove that word and replace it with the number it represents.(so it becomes `[4,t,r,e,s,s]`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a single replacement:

```
text_l33t(W, L33t) :-
   rule(A, B),
   phrase( ( seq(Pre), seq(A), seq(Post) ), W),
   phrase( ( seq(Pre), seq(B), seq(Post) ), L33t).

seq([]) -->
   [].
seq([E|Es]) -->
   [E],
   seq(Es).
```

Alternatively, you could express that relation with `append/3`, but with even minimally more complex examples, `append/3` will make things much more difficult to handle.

Consider also to use the Prolog flag `double_quotes` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) because it permits you to use double quotes. You could then write `rule("to","2").  rule("ight","ite").`  and get back nice answer substitutions, like so:

```
?- text_l33t("right", L).
   L = "rite".
```

---

If you want optionally more than one replacement, things become a bit more complex to specify. What about overlapping different rewrites? What about rewrites that get longer and longer? The following definition incorporates *all possible* rewrites:

```
text_xl33t(W, W).
text_xl33t(W, L33t) :-
   text_l33t(W, L0),
   text_xl33t(L0, L33t).
```

What you probably want is a maximal rewrite. While you can write this down in Prolog, I would not do this as a beginner: You are leaving the pure monotonic part of Prolog for that.

---

Edit: It seems you are still not happy with what I described. So here is `text_maxl33t/2`:

```
text_maxl33t(W, L33t) :-
   text_xl33t(W, L33t),
   \+ text_l33t(L33t, _).
```

Note that this predicate is still a relation. That is, for a single word you might have several independent maxl33ts since rewriting is not necessarily confluent.

Comment: Thank you! And what about if in a word you have to make 2 or more replacements. (For example if the word is "foryeahfor")

Comment: Hi, the edit for more replacements does not work. It returns the same list that is input.