# Replacing white spaces in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, iso-prolog

Is it possible in prolog to replace all white spaces of a string with some given character?
Example-
If I have a variable `How are you today?`  and I want `How_are_you_today?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For atoms

There are may ways in which this can be done. I find the following particularly simple, using [`atomic_list_concat/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/3):

```
?- atomic_list_concat(Words, ' ', 'How are you today?'), atomic_list_concat(Words, '_', Result).
Words = ['How', are, you, 'today?'],
Result = 'How_are_you_today?'.
```

### For SWI strings

The above can also be done with SWI strings. Unfortunately, there is no `string_list_concat/3` which would have made the conversion trivial. [`split_string/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=split_string/4) is very versatile, but it only does half of the job:

```
?- split_string("How are you today?", " ", "", Words).
Words = ["How", "are", "you", "today?"].
```

We can either define `string_list_concat/3` ourselves (a first attempt at defining this is shown below) or we need a slightly different approach, e.g. repeated [`string_concat/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=string_concat/3).

```
string_list_concat(Strings, Separator, String):-
  var(String), !,
  maplist(atom_string, [Separator0|Atoms], [Separator|Strings]),
  atomic_list_concat(Atoms, Separator0, Atom),
  atom_string(Atom, String).
string_list_concat(Strings, Separator, String):-
  maplist(atom_string, [Separator0,Atom], [Separator,String]),
  atomic_list_concat(Atoms, Separator0, Atom),
  maplist(atom_string, Atoms, Strings).
```

And then:

```
?- string_list_concat(Words, " ", "How are you today?"), string_list_concat(Words, "_", Result).
Words = ["How", "are", "you", "today?"],
Result = "How_are_you_today?".
```

Comment: Ok so basically it is converting string into lists and then back to string..Thanks a lot it worked.

Comment: @Peter Yet, notice that when you use the word "string" you actually mean "atom". SWI-Prolog also supports strings, but this is non-standard. I'll add a similar solution for splitting SWI strings to my answer.

Comment: @false Can't say that was entirely intentional ;-), but it may be just fine for this particular case.

Comment: Your nonvar-test make things worse, because it now fails for the most general query. I'd rather test for **one** `var/1` and then rely on the built-ins to do the rest.

Comment: @false Thanks, I've improved my definition a bit. It's still not quite there, e.g. `string_list_concat([], "/", "")` fails. However, I have never liked the fact that both `atomic_list_concat([], '/', '')` and `atomic_list_concat([''], '/', '')` succeed...

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what you mean by a string.  SWI has several for them, some are generally available in any common Prolog and conforming to the ISO standard ; and some are specific to SWI and not conforming. So, let's start with those that are generally available:

###Strings as list of character codes — integers representing code points

This representation is often the default, prior to SWI 7 it was the default in SWI, too. The biggest downside is that a list of arbitrary integers can now be confused with text.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).

codes_replaced(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(space_repl, Xs, Ys).

space_repl(0' ,0'_).
space_repl(C, C) :- dif(C,0' ).

?- codes_replaced("Spaces  !", R).
   R = [83,112,97,99,101,115,95,95,33]
;  false.
```

###Strings as list of characters — atoms of length 1

This representation is a bit cleaner since it does not confuse integers with characters, see [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) how to get more compact answers.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

chars_replaced(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(space_replc, Xs, Ys).

space_replc(' ','_').
space_replc(C, C) :- dif(C,' ').

?- chars_replaced("Spaces  !", R).
   R = ['S',p,a,c,e,s,'_','_',!]
;  false.
```

###Strings as atoms

@WouterBeek already showed you how this can be done with an SWI-specific built-in. I will reuse above:

```
atom_replaced(A, R) :-
   atom_chars(A, Chs),
   chars_replaced(Chs, Rs),
   atom_chars(R, Rs).

?- atom_replaced('Spaces  !',R).
   R = 'Spaces__!'
;  false.
```

So far everything applies to [iso-prolog](/questions/tagged/iso-prolog)

###Strings as an SWI-specific, non-conforming data type

This version does not work in any other system. I mention it for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog DCGs allows an easy definition, using 'push back' or lookahead argument:

```
?- phrase(rep_string(` `, `_`), `How are you`, R),atom_codes(A,R).
R = [72, 111, 119, 95, 97, 114, 101, 95, 121|...],
A = 'How_are_you'
```

The definition is

```
rep_string(Sought, Replace), Replace --> Sought, rep_string(Sought, Replace).
rep_string(Sought, Replace), [C] --> [C], rep_string(Sought, Replace).
rep_string(_, _) --> [].
```

*edit* To avoid multiple 'solutions', a possibility is

```
rep_string(Sought, Replace), Replace --> Sought, !, rep_string(Sought, Replace).
rep_string(Sought, Replace), [C] --> [C], !, rep_string(Sought, Replace).
rep_string(_, _) --> [].
```

Comment: Try to type `;` or `SPACE` so see what happens: You get more than one answer. BTW: backquoted strings meaning codes is SWI-specific.