# Prolog String-Intensive Algorithm Crashes

Tags: string, prolog

I am writing an algorithm to process a string, and it crashes (possibly due to a quirk in Prolog which makes string-intensive algorithms crash).  How can I modify the algorithm so that it doesn't crash?

The algorithm replaces `"`, `“`, `”`, `‘` and `’` with `'`, and `\\` and `-`  with nothing and breaks the string on `\n\n`.

It takes the inputted files:

`raw_sources`:
`1.txt`:

```
a
a

B
b
b

C
c
c
```

```
`2.txt`:
```

```
“”‘’'"
\\
- 


b
```

And outputs the files:

`sources`:
`1.txt`:

```
["a
a","B
b
b","C
c
c"]
```

```
`2.txt`:
```

```
["''''''","
b"]
```

The query:
`sheet_feeder(_).`

The code so far:

```
sheet_feeder(T) :-
    directory_files("raw_sources/",F),
    delete_invisibles_etc(F,G),
    findall(K1,(member(H,G),        
    atom_concat('raw_sources/',H,String00b),
    phrase_from_file(string(String001), String00b),
    string_codes(String000,String001),
    string_concat(String000,"\n\n",String00_a),
    strip_illegal_chars(String00_a,"",String00),
        split_on_substring(String00,"\n\n",[],J1),
        delete(J1,"",K1),
        term_to_atom(K1,K),
        string_concat("sources/",H,String00bb),
    (open(String00bb,write,Stream1),
    write(Stream1,K),
    close(Stream1))
        ),T).

delete_invisibles_etc(F,G) :-
    findall(J,(member(H,F),
    atom_string(H,J),
    not(J="."),not(J=".."),not(string_concat(".",_,J))),G).

string(String) --> list(String).

list([]) --> [].
list([L|Ls]) --> [L], list(Ls).
    
strip_illegal_chars("",A,A) :- !.
strip_illegal_chars(A,B,E) :-
    string_concat(E1,D,A),
    string_length(E1,1),
    E1="\\",
    string_concat(B,"",F),
    strip_illegal_chars(D,F,E),!.
strip_illegal_chars(A,B,E) :-
    string_concat(E1,D,A),
    string_length(E1,2),
    E1="- ",
    string_concat(B,"",F),
    strip_illegal_chars(D,F,E),!.
strip_illegal_chars(A,B,E) :-
    string_concat(E1,D,A),
    string_length(E1,1),
    ((E1="\"" -> true;
    (E1="“" -> true;
    (E1="”" -> true;
    (E1="‘" -> true;
    (E1="’" -> true;
    (E1="'"))))))),
    string_concat(B,"'",F),
    strip_illegal_chars(D,F,E),!.
strip_illegal_chars(A,B,E) :-
    string_concat(C,D,A),
    string_length(C,1),
    string_concat(B,C,F),
    strip_illegal_chars(D,F,E),!.
    
split_on_substring([],_A,E,[E]) :- !. %% ***?
split_on_substring(A,B,E,C) :-
    append(B,D,A),
    split_on_substring(D,B,[],C1),
    string_codes(E1,E),
    append([E1],C1,C),!.
split_on_substring(A,B,E1,C) :-
    length(E,1),
    append(E,D,A),
    append(E1,E,E2),
    split_on_substring(D,B,E2,C),!.
```

Comment: If you are using SWI-Prolog, it has bindings for PCRE. <https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pcre> just use that if it is good enough. If you cannot use regular expressions, you need to be actually parsing.

Comment: I know it, but write my own expanded code.

Comment: Why not use DCGs?

Comment: It is simpler to use replacement as it does. The algorithm just replaces characters from input.

Comment: With too much input, there is a performance error.

Answer (score 0):

I stored the string as string codes to overcome the performance difficulties.  Apparently, string_concat duplicates both the string concatenated and what is concatenated to it, but append just copies what is appended on to a list.

The solution:

```
sheet_feeder(T) :-
    directory_files("raw_sources/",F),
    delete_invisibles_etc(F,G),
    findall(K1,(member(H,G),        
    atom_concat('raw_sources/',H,String00b),
    phrase_from_file(string(String001), String00b),
    append(String001,`\n\n`,String00_a),
    strip_illegal_chars(String00_a,[],String00),
        split_on_substring(String00,`\n\n`,[],J1),
        delete(J1,"",K1),
        term_to_atom(K1,K),
        string_concat("sources/",H,String00bb),
    (open(String00bb,write,Stream1),
    write(Stream1,K),
    close(Stream1))
        ),T).

delete_invisibles_etc(F,G) :-
    findall(J,(member(H,F),
    atom_string(H,J),
    not(J="."),not(J=".."),not(string_concat(".",_,J))),G).

string(String) --> list(String).

list([]) --> [].
list([L|Ls]) --> [L], list(Ls).
    
strip_illegal_chars([],A,A) :- !.
strip_illegal_chars(A,B,E) :-
    length(E1,1),
    append(E1,D,A),
    E1=[92],
    append(B,``,F),
    strip_illegal_chars(D,F,E),!.
strip_illegal_chars(A,B,E) :-
    length(E1,2),
    append(E1,D,A),
    E1=`- `,
    append(B,``,F),
    strip_illegal_chars(D,F,E),!.
strip_illegal_chars(A,B,E) :-
    length(E1,1),
    append(E1,D,A),
    ((E1=`"` -> true;
    (E1=[8220] -> true;
    (E1=[8221] -> true;
    (E1=[8216] -> true;
    (E1=[8217] -> true;
    (E1=`'`))))))),
    append(B,`'`,F),
    strip_illegal_chars(D,F,E),!.
strip_illegal_chars(A,B,E) :-
    length(C,1),
    append(C,D,A),
    append(B,C,F),
    strip_illegal_chars(D,F,E),!.
    
split_on_substring([],_A,E,E) :- !. %% ***?
split_on_substring(A,B,E,C) :-
    append(B,D,A),
    split_on_substring(D,B,[],C1),
    string_codes(E1,E),
    append([E1],C1,C),!.
split_on_substring(A,B,E1,C) :-
    length(E,1),
    append(E,D,A),
    append(E1,E,E2),
    split_on_substring(D,B,E2,C),!.
```

Comment: Given that lists of codes (or chars) uses so many much memory than strings, I wonder what problem you fixed... and of course SWI-Prolog mantainers would be interested as well, I think...

Comment: I got the idea by reading about the new command with_output_to on `https://github.com/kamahen/swipl-server-js-client/blob/master/simple_server.pl` (retweeted by SWI_Prolog) which addresses the performance issue.

Comment: I found a better way to replace strings at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973951/replacing-white-spaces-in-prolog#26974021