# prolog single quote (') unification

Tags: prolog, unification

I'm trying to unify variable X with '*' (including the quote marks, for a total of 3-symbol string)
What I'm doing is a simple `X='*'.`, but that results in X having the value `*`. If I go for `X=''*''.`, the result is `X=''*''`. I'm confused, how can I achieve the `'*'`?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly want a *string*, you should use double-quotes:

```
X="'*'".
```

If you want to make a *symbol*, you can use

```
atom_codes( X, "'*'" ).
```

Comment: This results in X being unified with the [39,42,39] list, I do realise that's the prolog representation of a string, but that's not what I was trying to achieve, I'd like X to be printed as '*'. It doesn't have to be a string, I just don't know what instruction should I use

Comment: Thank you, `atom_codes(X, "'*'").` worked like a charm, it said I need to use character escape \, as in `X = '\'*\''`