# Solving constraints with string concatenations in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Here, I tried to solve some simple string constraints in Prolog. While this problem seems to be straightforward, the `main` predicate still does not print the value of `FinalString`, which should be `"hello world"`. Is it possible for Prolog to solve constraints that contain string concatenations, like this one?

```
:- set_prolog_flag(verbose,silent).
:- prompt(_, '').
:- use_module(library(readutil)).
main :-
    append("hello ", B, FinalString),
    append(A, "world", FinalString),
    append(A, B, FinalString),
    writeln(FinalString),
    true.
:-main.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do experiments as a beginner, better stick to using the [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel). In this manner you can rapidily identify the problem. Since you are most probably using SWI7 - like so:

```
?- append("hello ", B, FinalString),
   append(A, "world", FinalString),
   append(A, B, FinalString).
   false.
```

So if this is false, lets **generalize** it, by removing the rightmost goal:

```
?- append("hello ", B, FinalString),
   append(A, "world", FinalString).
   false.
```

Nah ...

```
?- append("hello ", B, FinalString).
   false.
```

The actual problem is that double quotes in SWI have now a non-conforming meaning. To get traditional behavior, call SWI with command line option `--traditional` and:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).
   true.
?- append("hello ", B, FS).
   FS = [h,e,l,l,o,' '|B].
```

For more on this flag see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868).

Now your original query produces a sensible answer:

```
?- append("hello ", B, FS),append(A, "world", FS),append(A, B, FS).
   B = [w,o,r,l,d], FS = [h,e,l,l,o,' ',w,o,r|...], A = [h,e,l,l,o,' ']
;  loops.
```

... or does it? It finds the answer you want, but at the same time, when being asked whether or not there is a further answer, it loops! Such problems can be easily detected when using the toplevel shell, but remain undetected with a script as yours. This loop is an inherent problem. There is no easy way out, because the fact that there is exactly one solution is caused **by all three goals together**.

If you really like to write it as a script, rather write it like so:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

main :-
    append("hello ", B, FinalString),
    append(A, "world", FinalString),
    append(A, B, FinalString),
    write(FinalString),
    nl,
    halt.

:- initialization(main).
```

Comment: It might be easier to solve this problem using [constraint handling rule grammars](http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/~henning/chrg/CHRGusersGuide.html), which were designed to solve problems like this one.