# How do I surround an Atom value with double quotation marks in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

```
Id = 1,
Result= "1",
```

How do I surround the value in `Id` with double quotations? In the example above I have the value 1 stored in `Id` and I want to surround it with double quotations and store it in `Result`. How would I accomplish this using Prolog code?

Comment: You know that in Prolog you don't store values in variables? You "unify" the variable with an atom. That's a very different concept than storing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868 about what the syntax actually means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `atom_string/2`.

Example:

```
?- atom_string(1, R).
R = "1".

?- atom_string(abc, R).
R = "abc".
```