# Prolog: Different behaviour of single and double quotes

Tags: prolog, portability, double-quotes, prolog-assert

I'm quite new to Prolog and I stumbled on something that I don't understand.

This is my code:

```
:- dynamic user/3.
user('id', 'Name', 20).

changeAge(Id, NewAge) :-
   user(Id, Name, _),
   retract(user(Id,_,_)),
   assert(user(Id,Name,NewAge)).
```

To update user information in the database,
`changeAge/2` performs these three steps:

1. Lookup a right record, using `user/3`.
2. Remove one matching record from the database, using `retract/1`.
3. Insert a new updated record into the database, using `assert/1`.

This is my console output:

```
1 ?- user('id', _, Age).
Age = 20.

2 ?- changeAge('id', 25).
true.

3 ?- user('id', _, Age).
Age = 25.

4 ?- changeAge("id", 30).
false.

5 ?- user('id', _, Age).
Age = 25.
```

Why do single quotes give me `true` (line 2)
when double quotes give me `false` (line 4)?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR<sub><sub>1</sub></sub>:** 
Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) to the question
"[What is the difference between ' and " in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8264699/4609915)".

**TL;DR<sub><sub>2</sub></sub>:** The goal `'id' = "id"` succeeds [**iff**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the Prolog flag [double_quotes](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dlps_002dflg.html#ref_002dlps_002dflg) is set to `atom`.

The [Prolog flag](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dlps_002dflg.html) `double_quotes` can be set at runtime using `set_prolog_flag/2`:

- `?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).`

  ```
  ?- 'id' = "id".
  false.
  ```
- `?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).`

  ```
  ?- 'id' = "id".
  false.
  ```
- `?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, atom).`

  ```
  ?- 'id' = "id".
  true.
  ```

For more information read the [SICStus Prolog manual](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dsyn_002dcpt_002dsli.html#ref_002dsyn_002dcpt_002dsli) page on "[Strings as lists](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dsyn_002dcpt_002dsli.html)"!

Answer (score 2):

Let's say some users got multiple records for the same ID in the database; something that might have potential uses, say, if people may have more than one name... either way, this answer is not about getting the modeling part right, but about the technical aspects of [prolog-assert](/questions/tagged/prolog-assert)! **YMMV.**

```
:- dynamic(user/3).

init_db :-
   retractall(user(_,_,_)),
   maplist(assert, [user(i,n,1),user(i,n,2),user(i,m,1),user(i,m,2),
                    user(j,n,1),user(j,n,2),user(j,m,1),user(j,m,2)]).

changeAge(Id, NewAge) :-
   user(Id, Name, _),
   retract(user(Id,_,_)),
   assert(user(Id,Name,NewAge)).
```

Let's initialize the database and "change some ages" :-)

```
?- init_db, (changeAge(i,6) ; changeAge(j,7)), false.
false.

?- findall(user(Id,Name,Age), user(Id,Name,Age), DB).
DB = [user(i,m,6),user(i,m,6),user(i,m,6),user(i,m,6),
      user(j,m,7),user(j,m,7),user(j,m,7),user(j,m,7)].
```

*Bad!* in: 8 distinct records. out: 2 distinct records, each one having a multiplicity of 4.

Let's restore with above original facts and then use `changeAge/2` slightly differently:

```
?- init_db, changeAge(_,_), false.
false.

?- findall(user(Id,Name,Age), user(Id,Name,Age), DB).
DB = [user(i,m,_),user(i,m,_),user(i,m,_),user(i,m,_),
      user(j,m,_),user(j,m,_),user(j,m,_),user(j,m,_)].
```

*Even worse!* in: 8 distinct ground records. out: 2 distinct non-ground records.

**Bottom line:** 
Be mindful of the "handle with care" warning sign attached to [prolog-assert](/questions/tagged/prolog-assert)!