# How to check that a string contains only certain characters in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I want to write a predicate `containsOnly(X,Y)`, which returns true, if string `X` contains only characters from string Y.

I wrote it this way:

```
containsOnly([],_).
containsOnly([H|T],AcceptableCharacters) :- 
    member(H, AcceptableCharacters),
    containsOnly(T,AcceptableCharacters).
```

But the queries below return false. How can I modify the predicate in order for them to return true?

```
containsOnly('A', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÜabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöüАБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя-').
containsOnly('a', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÜabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöüАБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя-').
```

Comment: Please first read the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8264699/1613573) about the difference between `'` and `"` in Prolog, and the important flag `double_quotes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working with atoms, as in your question, an ISO compliant solution:

```
containsOnly(X,Y) :- forall(sub_atom(X,_,1,_,C), sub_atom(Y,_,1,_,C)).
```

while SWI-Prolog ver. >= 7 seems to accept it for 'strings' also.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the datatype. You use atoms, but you treat them as char/code lists. You can try use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` and see if this helps.

With SWI-Prolog 7 or later, it won't help. You would have to use backticks instead of double quotes.

You really should figure out the documentation and the datatypes though.

This is a list of codes in SWI-Prolog 7:

```
`абвгд`
```

And `0'x` is Prolog notation for character codes:

```
?- X = 0'г.
X = 1075.

?- X = `абв`.
X = [1072, 1073, 1074].
```

Another thing: if you are using SWI-Prolog, you should use `memberchk/2` instead of `member/2` in this particular case. If this is an efficiency bottleneck, however, you might also consider using the method described at the very bottom of [this page](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings). (This whole section of the manual is very important if you are going to be dealing with text in your SWI-Prolog program.)

Comment: Your answer is specific to SWI7 only. For a solution that works in all systems including SWI7, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868).

Comment: @false Yes, indeed. The question was tagged [swi-prolog], so I allowed myself this frivolity.