# How do I separate out elements on list by element?

Tags: prolog, ascii

I am writing a Prolog program for tokenization. Currently, I am able to get a list of ASCII code but I just don't know how to tokenize them to return a list of tokens.

For example, if I have:

```
[105,110,116,32,105,110,116,32,97,32,13,10,105,110,116,32],
```

how do I obtain: `[int,int,a,int]`?

I know the key is to read list by '32' and separate everything before 32 and append `[105,110,116]` to become 'int', I am new to list so I am not familiar with Prolog. Any help?

Comment: Just a general remark: To process text, you can also use lists of characters. They are much more readable. In your case: `[i,n,t,' ',i,n,t,' ',a,' ','\r','\n',i,n,t,' ']`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) for more!

Comment: Is there any predicate for appending ' ' to special characters like '?' ?@false

Comment: I don't get your question. A list of characters with `?` is `"?"` or `[?]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic knowledge about `DCG` woudl be usefull here. Let say you get ascii code using `read_lines_to_codes/2` i.e `read_lines_to_code(user_input,X).` so with input `{}` you recive `X = [123, 125].` so with DCG defined like that

```
lekserr(Tokens) -->
(   ( "{", !, {Token = tkLbrabce }
    ;    "}", !, {Token =  tkRBrace}
    ;    "int", !, {Token = tkInt}
    ),
    !,
    {Tokens = [Token| TokList]},
    lekserr(TokList)
;   [],
    {Tokens = []}
).
```

when you do

```
read_line_to_codes(user_input,X), phrase(lekserr(Y),X).
|    int
X = [105, 110, 116],
Y = [tkInt].
```

It's just brief and i hope you find it usefull, consider adding clause to ignore whitespaces.