# Remove adjacent duplicates in a list with Prolog

Tags: prolog

I found a similar post but it didn't work for me. So please don't try to redirect me to other links.

This is the result that I want:

```
removeadj([a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a],[a,b,c,a]).
>True.
```

I tried this code:

```
concatener([],R,R). 
concatener([X|Y],L,R):-concatener(Y,L,R1),R=[X|R1].

removeadj([],[]).
removeadj([X],[X]).
removeadj([X|Y],R):- Y=[X|L],removeadj(Y,R1),concatener([],R1,R).
removeadj([X|Y],R):- removeadj(Y,R1),concatener(X,R1,R).
```

When I try a list with one element duplicated many times, it works:

```
removeadj([a,a,a,a,a],[a]).
> True
```

But when I use different elements, it doesn't work:

```
removeadj([a,a,a,b],[a,b]). 
> False.
```

I do not see where the problem is, so I can't fix it. Please I need your help.

Comment: Doesn't `concatener([], R1, R)` do the same thing as `R = R1`? And `concatener(X, R1, R)` doesn't make sense because `X` is a list element, not a list. If you want to prepend `X` to list `R1` resulting in `R`, just use `[X|R1] = R`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the mistake. X is an element. I made that modification: concatener(X,R1,R) to concatener([X],R1,R) and it is working now.

Comment: You can just use `R = [X|R1]`

Comment: Which link did not work?

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfy your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Relational names

The first is to reconsider the name of your relation. Currently, it suggests that someone has to do something. `removeadj` that's a command. Quite an adequate name in a programming language where commands are the ruling metaphor. But not in Prolog.

In Prolog, we have relations. A name that reflects this relationness is often very helpful. Why not `list_list/2`? After all, your relation is about two lists! OK, maybe that name was a bit too general. What about `list__list_without_adjacent_elements/2`? Lengthy, but relational. Maybe we shorten that to: `list_noadjs/2`. Note the `s` at the end: That means: it's a plural which means it's a list.

#### Observe properties

Before thinking about "doing" this or that. Rather muse about concrete examples - preferably ground examples, as you have given them. And about other properties.  One observation is that all elements of the second list will be there in the first. In fact not only that. But they will also occur in the same order. Let me try to formulate that. Of course, that observation is not sufficient to write an **entire** predicate. But here comes the cool thing in Prolog: We do not need to implement everything. We can start with gross generalizations that contain all what we want plus some more.

#### Start with a too general definition.

To show you the most extreme, let's try:

```
list_noadjs(_Xs, _Ys).
```

This is the mother of all binary relations! That definition always succeeds, no matter what. Evidently, we will have to specialize it.  Say, by looking at the second argument which is a list:

```
list_noadjs(_Xs, []).
list_noadjs(_Xs, [Y|Ys]) :-
   list_noadjs(_, Ys).
```

If the list is `[]` so will be the original one. And both start with the same element!

```
list_noadjs(Xs, []) :-
   Xs = [].
list_noadjs(Xs, [Y|Ys]) :-
   Xs = [Y|_],
   list_noadjs(_, Ys).
```

or more compactly:

```
list_noadjs([], []).
list_noadjs([Y|_Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
   list_noadjs(_, Ys).
```

Now, the first list contains elements of the second list. And in between something else:

```
list_noadjs([], []).
list_noadjs([Y|Xs0], [Y|Ys]) :-
   list_(Xs0,Xs1),
   list_noadjs(Xs1, Ys).

list_(Xs,Xs).
list_([_|Xs0],Xs) :-
   list_(Xs0,Xs).
```

Is this already our relation? Let's give it a try:

```
?- list_noadjs("aaab",Ys).
   Ys = "aaab"
;  Ys = "aaa"
;  Ys = "aab"
;  Ys = "aa"
;  Ys = "aab"
;  Ys = "aa"
;  Ys = "ab"  % <===== * RRRIGHT !!!!***
;  Ys = "a"
;  false.
```

(Btw. I am using [`library(double_quotes)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) to make answers more readable.)

So we do have the expected solution. Alas, there are many incorrect solutions, too! We will have to continue to specialize this program:

```
list_noadjs([], []).
list_noadjs([Y|Xs0], [Y|Ys]) :-
   eq_list_(Y, Xs0,Xs1),
   list_noadjs(Xs1, Ys).

eq_list_(_, Xs,Xs).
eq_list_(Y, [Y|Xs0],Xs) :-
   eq_list_(Y, Xs0,Xs).
```

Now this is much better, but still not perfect:

```
?- list_noadjs("aaab",Ys).
   Ys = "aaab"
;  Ys = "aab"
;  Ys = "aab"
;  Ys = "ab"    % !!! Right
;  false.
```

We have to further specialize the program: After a sequence of identical elements, there must be something else:

```
list_noadjs([], []).
list_noadjs([Y|Xs0], [Y|Ys]) :-
   eq_list_(Y, Xs0,Xs1),
   nohead(Xs1, Y),
   list_noadjs(Xs1, Ys).

eq_list_(_, Xs,Xs).
eq_list_(Y, [Y|Xs0],Xs) :-
   eq_list_(Y, Xs0,Xs).

nohead([], _X).
nohead([X|_], Y) :-
   dif(X, Y).
```

So that's our relation.

#### Enjoy the relation!

Seriously. Don't just use the test cases you had. You have now a relation! That's  not a function in disguise, it is truly more than that. Try it out! Ask completely unusual things, like:

```
?- list_noadjs(Xs,"abc").
   Xs = "abc"
;  Xs = "abcc"
;  Xs = "abccc"
;  Xs = "abcccc"
; ... .
```

So here we ask: Which lists correspond to `"abc"`? Note that only `c` is repeated! All the other solutions are hidden behind this wall of infinity. But we can play a little trick to get them:

```
?- length(Xs,N), list_noadjs(Xs,"abc").
   Xs = "abc", N = 3
;  Xs = "abcc", N = 4
;  Xs = "abbc", N = 4
;  Xs = "aabc", N = 4
;  Xs = "abccc", N = 5
;  Xs = "abbcc", N = 5
;  Xs = "abbbc", N = 5
;  Xs = "aabcc", N = 5
;  Xs = "aabbc", N = 5
;  Xs = "aaabc", N = 5
;  Xs = "abcccc", N = 6
; ... .
```

#### Don't shy away from non-termation.

We have already seen it: Very often, we get infinitely many solutions. And (I must admit) it's even worse: Sometimes, our relations do not even terminate.

Here is one such example. Say, is there a way that the list in the second argument contains duplicates? Or that the following holds:

```
?- list_noadjs(Xs,[X,X]).
   loops.
```

Prolog answers: mumble, mumble, lemme see...

To master Prolog, you will have to understand this in detail. But for the moment, there is often a good way out:

#### Specialize queries to get termination

So instead of asking: Is there **any** term that may correspond to `[X,X]` we may ask: Is there a list of size 5 (or any other finite size). Now Prolog denies this:

```
 ?- Xs = [_,_,_,_,_], list_noadjs(Xs,[X,X]).
    false.
```

That's not the universal answer you wanted. But it is better than nothing.

Sometimes all these queries are too much for you. Let Prolog do the thinking for you by:

#### Enumerating all solutions

Often, this is very simple. Start with the most general query. The big advantage here is that **no thinking is required** on your side at all. And still you look like a pro:

```
?- list_noadjs(Xs,Ys).
   Xs = [], Ys = []
;  Xs = [_A], Ys = [_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_B], Ys = [_A,_B], dif(_B,_A)
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C], Ys = [_A,_B,_C], dif(_B,_A), dif(_C,_B) ?
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D], Ys = [_A,_B,_C,_D], dif(_B,_A), dif(_C,_B), dif(_D,_C)
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E], Ys = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E], dif(_B,_A), dif(_C,_B), dif(_D,_C)
;  ... .
```

What we got here are so called **answers**. A single answer may contain **infinitely** many solutions. Think of this: You are looking at infinity! Some conditions (called **constraints**) must hold, like `dif/2`. But that's it.

The third answer was:

```
Xs = [_A,_B], Ys = [_A,_B], dif(_B,_A)
```

So `Xs` and `Ys` are the same list with two distinct elements. So this answer implies `Xs = "ab", Ys = "ab"` but also `Xs = [1,2], Ys = [1,2]` and many, many more.

Even better, enumerate all answers in a systematic ("fair") manner:

```
?- length(Xs, N), list_noadjs(Xs,Ys).
   Xs = [], N = 0, Ys = []
;  Xs = [_A], N = 1, Ys = [_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_B], N = 2, Ys = [_A,_B], dif(_B,_A)
;  Xs = [_A,_A], N = 2, Ys = [_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C], N = 3, Ys = [_A,_B,_C], dif(_B,_A), dif(_C,_B)
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_B], N = 3, Ys = [_A,_B], dif(_B,_A)
;  Xs = [_A,_A,_B], N = 3, Ys = [_A,_B], dif(_B,_A)
;  Xs = [_A,_A,_A], N = 3, Ys = [_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D], N = 4, Ys = [_A,_B,_C,_D], dif(_B,_A), dif(_C,_B), dif(_D,_C)
; ... .
```

These are **all solutions** up to length 3. There are no other! We know this for sure because the last answer is already of size 4. So all solutions below are here already!

Often looking at such answers is very helpful. For example, it permits you to rapidly detect errors (like in the other answer that was given previously). So, don't tell nobody about that trick.

Answer (score 1):

The last clause in the predicate still has an issue:

```
removeadj([X|Y], [X|R1]):- removeadj(Y, R1).
```

In the event that the element following `X` is also `X`, `X` is still carried in the head of the second argument. This clause must check if the following element is different before allowing it in the second argument:

```
removeadj([X,Y|L], [X|R]) :-
    dif(X,Y),
    removeadj([Y|L], R).
```

Here, `Y` is at the head of the second list only if it's different from `X`.

So the whole solution looks like:

```
removeadj([], []).
removeadj([X], [X]).
removeadj([X,X|T], R) :-       % drop an X if next element is X
    removeadj([X|T], R).
removeadj([X,Y|T], [X|R]) :-   % carry X along if next element different
    dif(X,Y),
    removeadj([Y|T], R).
```

Comment: `removeadj([a,a,a],[a,a,a]).` succeeds.

Comment: @false thanks, good catch. I was a bit hasty in transcribing the predicate.

Comment: Now, `removeadj("abc","abc").` fails.

Comment: @false. your last comment appears to be obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

```
removeadj([],[]).
removeadj([X],[X]).
removeadj([X|Y],R):- Y=[X|L],removeadj(Y,R1),R=R1.
removeadj([X|Y],[X|R1]):- removeadj(Y,R1).
```

Comment: More concise: `removeadj([X|Y], [X|R1]) :- removeadj(Y, R1).`

Comment: Thanks, so in that case there is no need to "Concatener".

Comment: That's correct. If you concatenate a fixed number of elements with an arbitrary list, concatenate predicate is not needed. For example, if you want to prepend `[X,Y]` to `L` you would just have `Result = [X,Y|L]`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: `removeadj([a,a,b], [a,a,b]).` succeeds. So nothing is removed.

Comment: @false yes there's still a problem with the clause, `removeadj([X|Y],[X|R1]):- removeadj(Y,R1).` I was commenting only on the syntax, not the correctness of the clause.