# match a string in prolog

Tags: prolog, string-matching

How can Prolog be used to parse this arbitrary string?

```
S → DZ 
D → dD 
D → d 
Z → zZ
Z → z
```

So far I have this code, but it has proven ineffective.
A represents the input and B represents the resulting string.

```
s(A,B):- d(A,C), z(C,B).
d([d,d|A],A).
z(z,z|A],A).
```

Comment: Take a loo at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36845526/1243762) for ideas.

Comment: *but it has proven ineffective.* Could you be specific? What query did you try? What results did you expect? What results did you get?