# How do you join characters in a list together in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Eg: ["c","h","a","r"] should print "char".

its atomic_list_concat(), but how would I do it for eg:

```
longest_common_prefix([H1,H2|T], P) :-
    maplist(append(P), L, [H1,H2|T]).
```

Comment: By writing a predicate to do that...

Answer (score 5):

Using `library(double_quotes)` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868), we can use `append/2` (note the 2!) :

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes).
   true.

?- append(["c","h","a","r"], Cs).
   Cs = "char".
```

However, please note that `"c"` is **not** a character! It is a list with one character. One single character is `c` alone.  And most of the times, you do not need to write `"c"`

```
?- [c,h,a,r] = "char".
   true.
```

Comment: Thanks, all this time I have been thinking "c" is a character!

Answer (score 1):

in SWI-Prolog

```
?- atomic_list_concat( ["c","h","a","r"] , L).
L = char.
```

but things become hairier soon... you should take the time to learn about elementary data representation for anything serious

Comment: thanks, the problem is i dont know how to use it for my predicate, i'm new to Prolog. Any ideas?

Comment: just obvious ones... out the call where required, into your rule body