# Prolog concatenate all elements inside a list to make a string?

Tags: string, list, prolog

How would I concatenate all the elements in a list together in prolog? I am trying to integrate it with my current function that outputs a list.

input = [a,b,c,d]

output = "abcd"

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you input list contains characters then use this: Here list contains Characters and in X you get result back.

```
concate(X,List):-
   atom_chars(X,List).
```

For this query you get result as this:

```
concate(X,[a,b,c,d]).
  X = abcd.
```

Here X gets result as atom not string.

Now if you want a string back and you list contains atoms then you use this:

```
atomsToString(List,X):-
    atomics_to_string(List,X).
```

With this query:

```
?- atomsToString([a,b,c,d],X).
X = "abcd".
```

Here X contains a string.