# Select/3 to remove a random character from string fails

Tags: prolog

Edit: Solved it by first turning the String into a list with string_chars/2. Still not sure why that was needed. I thought strings were already char lists in prologs mind.

Not the best at prolog but I have to use it for this task. I want to write a predicate that will remove characters from a string untill the string is an palindrome. I have palindrome/1, which seems to work correctly.

I've tried this:

```
predicate(String):-
    palindrome(String).
predicate(String):-
    select(_, String, NewString), % Idea: Removing a character from String will give NewString
    predicate(NewString).
```

So something like `predicate("addal")` should give true, but gives me false.

In fact, adding some break-points in the code, like writing "Reached" at different points in the program shows that the program fails at `select(_, String, NewString)`

Why doesn't select/3 work? The idea is to just remove a random character.

Edit: Its a palindrome, not an anagram like i said at first.

Comment: `I want to write a predicate that will remove characters from a string until the string is an anagram.` Which characters, the start, middle, end? How many characters? 1, 2 any number of them. If all of the characters but one character is removed then it is always an anagram.

Comment: @GuyCoder I meant to say palindrome, not anagram. It should remove any 1 character at any index in the string. I thought that if you say "remove 1 char from S" prolog will try every possible way to remove 1 char.

Comment: "Still not sure why that was needed." I suggest you read the documentation. Then you'd know why it was needed. But the bottom line is, Prologs are different. It is not just "Prolog".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the Prolog you are using. This is why it doesn't hurt to show *exactly* what you did.

```
$ gprolog
Compiled Jul 15 2018, 03:47:56 with gcc
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2018 Daniel Diaz
| ?- select(X, "foo", Rest).

Rest = [111,111]
X = 102 ? ;

Rest = [102,111]
X = 111 ? ;

Rest = [102,111]
X = 111 ? ;

no
| ?- 

$ swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.3-26-g30498cd0a)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- select(X, "foo", Rest).
false.

?- string_codes("foo", Codes), select(X, Codes, Rest).
Codes = [102, 111, 111],
X = 102,
Rest = [111, 111] ;
Codes = [102, 111, 111],
X = 111,
Rest = [102, 111] ;
Codes = [102, 111, 111],
X = 111,
Rest = [102, 111].
```

In "normal" Prolog, `"this is a list of character codes"`. In SWI-Prolog, `"this is a string"` and it is **not** a list, it is an atomic thingy that represents a string. You need to convert it to a list.

Comment: In both, SWI and GNU, `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

To [make your program work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) on any modern Prolog including SWI:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

Explicit conversion qua `atom_chars/2` or `string_chars/2` makes your program unnecessarily moded.  That is, you will always have to provide a full string say `"abc"`.  With strings as character lists, this means `[a,b,c]` which in turn can be generalized to `[a,X,c]` or any term that has `[a,b,c]` as an instance. There is no way how you can generalize SWI's strings in such a manner.

Such generalizations are extremely useful in Prolog.  You lose a lot if you give up on them.