# Creating a list of interleaved elements: Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am defining a function alternate_func(Ps, P) where Ps is a list of lists and P is a list of all elements in Ps that behaves in the following way: .

```
?- alternate_func([[p,q],[r,s]],P). 
P=[p,r,q,s]. (case 1)

?- alternate_func([P,Q,R],[p,q,r,s,t,u]). 
P=[p,s], Q=[q,t], R=[r,u]. (case 2)

?- alternate_func([Q],[1,2,3]). 
Q=[1,2,3]. (case 3)

?- alternate_func([[4,5,6],[3,1],[4,1,2]],X).
false. (because Length of sublists must be same) (case 4)
```

This is what I have tried so far,

```
alternate_func([[], L], L).          
alternate_func([[H|T], []], [H|T]).  

alternate_func([[X|L1], [Y|L2]], [X,Y|L3]) :-
    alternate_func([L1, L2], L3).
```

I am getting correct result for the case 1 but fails for the 2,3 and 4. What is the problem here?

Comment: Do all sublists have to have the same length?

Comment: Yes, they have to be of the same length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution processes the list of lists splitting the head / tail off each list. 
Afterwards:

- If all tails are empty we are done.
- Otherwise the process is repeated again, with the tails.

Code:

```
lists_interleaved( Ess, Es):-
  lists_interleaved( Ess, X-X, Es).

lists_interleaved( [], Head-[], []):-
  maplist(=([]), Head).
lists_interleaved( [], [First|Head]-[], Es):-
  lists_interleaved( [First|Head], X-X, Es).
lists_interleaved( [[E|ETail]|Ess], Head-[ETail|Rest], [E|Es]):-
  lists_interleaved( Ess, Head-Rest, Es).
```

Comment: What is this X-X notation? I have never come across it?

Comment: @Katherine `X-X` is the same as `-(X,X)` is the same as `p(X,X)` or `q(X,X)` etc., with arbitrary name `-`, `p`, `q`, or whatever. it is just a compound term holding two arguments, written in infix notation.

Comment: @Katherine here's [my re-write](https://gist.github.com/WillNess/0b6f19cea9b084d129bb0af1b048106c#file-so-55795221-md) of this code. see if it is easier to follow. :)

Comment: `is_prime(N):- length(L,N), findall(X, lists_interleaved( X, L), [_,_]).` !!! :) :)

Comment: @WillNess: Interesting observation... After thinking a bit it makes sense.

Comment: another one: `factors(Num,M*N):- length(L,Num), lists_interleaved( X, L), maplist(length,X,[M|_]), length(X,N).` :) --- but that is of course a ***very*** roundabout way to do just the same as `factors(Num, M*N):- findall(A, between(1,Num, A),As), reverse(As,Bs), member(M,Bs), N is Num div M, Num is M*N.`......

Comment: Any reason why `'='([])` is preferable to `=([])`?

Answer (score 3):

First, stick to good naming of relations. There is no `func`tion here. You have a relation between a list of lists and a list. So a name `lists_interleaved(Ess, Es)` is preferable.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).  % to permit that "abc" = [a,b,c]

lists_interleaved(Ess, Es) :-
   transpose(Ess, EssT),
   phrase(seqq(EssT), Es).          % alternatively append(EssT,Es)
```

See the definition of [`seqq//1`](/a/55515647/772868).

Still this is not the nicest definition. After all, `?- lists_interleaved(Ess, "abcd").` does not terminate. Let's use a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) to see why:

```
lists_interleaved(Ess, Es) :-
   transpose(Ess, EssT), false,
   phrase(seqq(EssT), Es). 

?- lists_interleaved(Ess, "abcd"), false.
   loops.
```

A simple way to fix this is to establish a relation between `Ess` and `Es`.
After all, the first list in `Ess` can be at most as long as `Es`, and also `Ess` cannot be longer.

By adding these restrictions as extra goals, we get:

```
lists_interleaved(Ess, Es) :-
   Ess = [Fs|_],
   Fs = [_|_],
   list_longer(Ess, Es),
   list_longer(Fs, Es),
   transpose(Ess, EssT),
   phrase(seqq(EssT), Es).

list_longer([], _).
list_longer([_|Es], [_|Fs]) :-
   list_longer(Es, Fs).
```

This now constrains us to an `Es` with at least one element.

```
?- lists_interleaved(Ess, "abcdef").
   Ess = ["abcdef"]
;  Ess = ["ace","bdf"]
;  Ess = ["ad","be","cf"]
;  Ess = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
;  false.
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) how to print solutions using compact double-quotes notation.

And still, this isn't perfect as these `list_longer/2` goals are now essentially guessing. But I will leave it as is since this is what you asked for.

(I will put a bounty for a better definition/or justification why this is not possible)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. `P = [_16262, _16268|_16270].` is what i am getting for case 1. now, with your code. Rest of the cases fail as well. I don't have an issue with quotes, my earlier code ran fine for case 1. Can you please help me?

Comment: You probably added the improved version as a separate rule. To avoid any ambiguity, I have now given the entire program.  And, of course all of your cases work. It is even better than that! The case `lists_interleaved(Ess, "abcdef").` is more general than the cases you asked for.

Comment: Hi, I understood what I did wrong. I was getting `Undefined procedure: transpose/2` and `Undefined procedure: seqq/3` so defined those using their definitions I found in swipl-devel/clpfd.pl. And then it worked for 3/4 cases. Still fails for case no. 2 with `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`.

Comment: Use `clpfd:lists_transpose(Ess, EssT),` instead. This version has much too much error checking.