# Converting a string to a list in sicstus prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm making a chess-like game and, in order to make the various moves, I want to read some user input like "11-12" to move the piece located at the "coordinates" 1-1 to the position 1-2. I want to convert the string "11-12" to a list like [1,1,-,1,2]. I would like to end up with something like this:

```
...
read(Play),
convert_play_to_list_L(Play, L),
element_at(StartX,L,1),
element_at(StartY,L,2),
element_at(EndX,L,3),
element_at(EndY,L,4),
...
```

example:
Play = "1112" , L = [1,1,1,2] , StartX = 1 , StartY = 1 , EndX = 1  , EndY = 2

Comment: The most common way to do this is to use regular terms. That is, to type `11-22.` or `"1112".` instead of the same without the dot.

Comment: But how do I convert that to a list?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) for more. That is, it is already a list

Comment: I still don't understand how can I turn 'Play' into a list after reading it

Comment: It **is already** a list!

Comment: Please try to follow the link indicated. With the appropriate flag given there, ihe input `"abc".` is tantamount to `[a,b,c].`

Comment: I've got it working. I needed to add the "". Thanks a lot and sorry for being so "slow" :) . Do you know how to convert the ASCII codes into integers?

Comment: `number_chars/2`

Comment: With `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars)`, there are no ASCII-codes involved - as indicated in the answer I linked.