# Prolog translating words issue with capital letters

Tags: prolog

So this is my code base structure currently.

```
trans([], []).
trans([H|T], [NewH|NewT]):-
   means(H, NewH),
   trans(T,NewT).

means(one, uno) :- !.
means(two, dos) :- !.
means(X, X) :- !.
```

**Question1**

This works roughly the way I want it to. For example, if I type in the prolog compiler:

```
?- trans([bob, uno, dos], X).   
   X = [bob, uno, dos].
```

It answers correctly.  However if I insert an argument with a capital letter for example:

```
?- trans([Bob, uno, dos], X).
```

It throws a bunch of errors for some reason. How can I fix it so this doesn't happen?

**Question2**

Currently it returns the answer into a List of several words e.g (trans([bob, one, two], X). will return X = [bob, uno, dos].

How can I make it so it returns a list of my words connected? (Like this: X = [bob uno dos] )

Comment: Another issue: `trans([one],[one])` succeeds. So is one the translation of one? Certainly not. Instead of using cuts, consider putting `dif/2` goals into the last clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: `uno` is an atom. To make Bob an atom, use single quotes. Thus write `'Bob'`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) for more.

However, I cannot reproduce your claim that

> It throws a bunch of errors for some reason.

You need to give the true transscript for this.

Q2: Why do you need this? Most probably it is preferable to stick to Prolog syntax.  There is `atom_chars/2`, [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg), and `atom_concat/3` for this. But still, I believe you are needlessly transforming things.

Comment: Oh looks like the error was caused due to a small mistake I made using the sicstus software. it looks like it works if correctly if I use 'Bob' but if I use it without quotes it thinks that Bob=one for some reason and it translates it to uno. So [Bob, one, two] returns [uno, uno, dos]

Comment: RIght, `Bob` is a variable, and `'Bob'` an atom.

Answer (score 0):

If something starts with a capital letter in Prolog it always is interpreted as an Variable. That's just the syntax but you could work with strings. So

`trans(["Bob", "uno", "dos"], X).`

That should also solve your second question if I get it right because then you want it to return

`X = "Bob uno dos"`