# Should text-processing DCGs be written to handle codes or chars? Or both?

Tags: prolog, char, dcg

In Prolog, there are traditionally two ways of representing a sequence of characters:

- As a list of *chars*, which are atoms of length 1.
- As a list of *codes*, which are just integers. The integers are to be interpreted as codepoints, but the convention to be applied is left unspecified. As a (eminently sane) example, in SWI-Prolog, the space of codepoints is *Unicode* (thus, roughly, the codepoint-integers range from 0 and 0x10FFFF).

DCGs, a notational way of writing left-to-right list processing code, are designed to perfom parsing on "lists of exploded text". Depending on preference, the lists to-be-handled can be lists of chars or lists of codes. However, the notation for char/code processing differs when writing down the constants. Does one generally write the DCG in "char style" or "code style"? Or maybe even in char/code style for portability in case of modules exporting DCG nonterminals?

## Some Research

### The following notations can be used to express constants in DCGs

- `'a'`: A *char* (as usual: single quotes indicate an atom, and they can be left out if the token starts with a lowercase letter.)
- `0'a`: the *code* of `a` .
- `['a','b']`: A list of *char*.
- `[ 0'a, 0'b ]`: A list of *codes*, namely the codes for `a` and `b` (so you can avoid typing in the actual codepoint values).
- `"a"` a list of *codes*. Traditionally, a double-quoted string is exploded into a list of *codes*, and this notation also works SWI-Prolog in DCG contexts, even though SWI-Prolog maps a "double-quoted string" to the special *string* datatype otherwise.
- `` `0123` ``. Traditonally, text within back-quotes is mapped to an atom (I think, the 95 ISO Standard just avoids being specific regarding the meaning of a back-quoted string. *"It would be a valid extension of this part of ISO/IEC 13211 to define a back quoted string as denoting a character string constant."*). In SWI-Prolog, text within back-quotes is exploded into a list of *codes* unless the flag [`back_quotes`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_prolog_flag/2#flag:back_quotes) has been set  to demand a different behaviour.

### Examples

### Char style

Trying to recognize "any digit" in "char style" and make its "char representation" available in `C`:

```
zero(C) --> [C],{C = '0'}. 

nonzero(C) --> [C],{member(C,['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])}.

any_digit(C) --> zero(C).
any_digit(C) --> nonzero(C).
```

### Code style

Trying to recognize "any digit" in "code style":

```
zero(C) --> [C],{C = 0'0}.

nonzero(C) --> [C],{member(C,[0'1,0'2,0'3,0'4,0'5,0'6,0'7,0'8,0'9])}.

any_digit(C) --> zero(C).
any_digit(C) --> nonzero(C).
```

### Char/Code transparent style

DCGs can be written as "char/code transparent style" by duplicating the rules involving constants. In the above example:

```
zero(C) --> [C],{C = '0'}. 
zero(C) --> [C],{C = 0'0}.

nonzero(C) --> [C],{member(C,['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])}.
nonzero(C) --> [C],{member(C,[0'1,0'2,0'3,0'4,0'5,0'6,0'7,0'8,0'9])}.

any_digit(C) --> zero(C).
any_digit(C) --> nonzero(C).
```

The above also *accepts* a sequence of alternating codes and chars (as lists of stuff cannot be typed). This is probably not a problem). When *generating*, one will get arbitrary char/code mixes which are unwanted, and then cuts need to be added.

### Char/Code transparent style taking an additional `Mode` indicator

Another approach would be to explicitly indicate the mode. Looks clean:

```
zero(C,chars) --> [C],{C = '0'}. 
zero(C,codes) --> [C],{C = 0'0}.

nonzero(C,chars) --> [C],{member(C,['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])}.
nonzero(C,codes) --> [C],{member(C,[0'1,0'2,0'3,0'4,0'5,0'6,0'7,0'8,0'9])}.

any_digit(C,Mode) --> zero(C,Mode).
any_digit(C,Mode) --> nonzero(C,Mode).
```

### Char/Code transparent style using dialect features

Alternatively, features of the Prolog dialect can be used to achieve char/code transparency. In SWI-Prolog, there is [`code_type/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=code_type/2), which actually works on codes and chars (there is a corresponding `char_type/2` but IMHO there should be only `chary_type/2` working for chars and codes in any case) and for "digit-class" codes and chars yield the compound `digit(X)`:

```
?- code_type(0'9,digit(X)).
X = 9.

?- code_type('9',digit(X)).
X = 9.

?- findall(W,code_type('9',W),B).
B = [alnum,csym,prolog_identifier_continue,ascii,
     digit,graph,to_lower(57),to_upper(57),
     digit(9),xdigit(9)].
```

And so one can write this for clean char/code transparency:

```
zero(C) --> [C],{code_type(C,digit(0)}. 

nonzero(C) --> [C],{code_type(C,digit(X),X>0}.

any_digit(C) --> zero(C).
any_digit(C) --> nonzero(C).
```

### In SWI-Prolog in particular

SWI-Prolog by default prefers **codes**. Try this:

The flags

- [`back_quotes`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_prolog_flag/2#flag:back_quotes)
- [`double_quotes`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_prolog_flag/2#flag:double_quotes)

influence interpretation of `"string"` and `` `string` `` in "standard code". By default`"string"` is interpreted as an atomic "string" whereas `` `string` `` is interpreted as a "list of codes".

Outside of DCGs, the following holds in SWI-Prolog, with all flags at their default:

```
?- string("foo"),\+atom("foo"),\+is_list("foo").
true.

?- L=`foo`.
L = [102,111,111].
```

However, in DCGs, both `"string"` and `` `string` `` are interpreted as "codes" by default.

Without any settings changed, consider this DCG:

```
representation(double_quotes)    --> "bar".            % SWI-Prolog decomposes this into CODES 
representation(back_quotes)      --> `bar`.            % SWI-Prolog decomposes this into CODES
representation(explicit_codes_1) --> [98,97,114].      % explicit CODES (as obtained via atom_codes(bar,Codes))
representation(explicit_codes_2) --> [0'b,0'a,0'r].    % explicit CODES 
representation(explicit_chars)   --> ['b','a','r'].    % explicit CHARS
```

Which of the above matches codes?

```
?- 
findall(X,
   (atom_codes(bar,Codes),
    phrase(representation(X),Codes,[])),
   Reps).

Reps = [double_quotes,back_quotes,explicit_codes_1,explicit_codes_2].
```

Which of the above matches chars?

```
?- findall(X,
   (atom_chars(bar,Chars),phrase(representation(X),Chars,[])),
   Reps).
Reps = [explicit_chars].
```

When starting swipl with `swipl --traditional` the backquoted representation is rejected with `Syntax error: Operator expected` , but otherwise nothing changes.

Comment: "... "a" a list of codes." This is not correct. The interpretation of a double-quoted term depends on the value of the standard `double_quotes` flag at the time the Prolog text is parsed.

Comment: @PauloMoura But in SWI-Prolog the `"foo"` is (by default, though that can be changed) the "string" with no further substructure. Using `"foo"` in a DCG, however, explodes it into codes. I will add an example.

Comment: Still, you keep making the **wrong claim** that `"a"` is list of codes. If the standard `double_quotes` flag is set to `atom`, then `"a"` is an atom. If the flag is set to `chars`, then `"a"` is a list of chars, `[a]`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about these things when writing DCG rules. Just use double-quoted "string" literals in the DCG rule definitions, those work as they should. No need to hack around with the concrete representation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Prolog Standard (6.3.7) says:

> A double quoted list is either an atom (6.3.1.3) or a list (6.3.5).

Consequently, the following should succeed:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.6.4)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- Foo = "foo", (atom(Foo) ; Foo = [F, O, O]).
false.
```

So SWI-Prolog is not a Prolog by default. That's OK, but if you want to know about SWI-Prolog's non-Prolog behavior, please adjust the tags on the question.

From the definition it also follows that double quoted lists *are completely useless by default* even in a conforming Prolog: They might denote atoms, so regardless of the chars/codes distinction you can't even know that the double quoted list is actually a list. Even DCGs that only care about structural properties of the "text" (whether it's a palindrome, for example) are useless if the "list" is in fact an atom.

Hence a Prolog program that wants to process text with DCGs **must** at startup force the `double_quotes` flag to the value it wants. You have the choice between codes and chars. Codes have no advantages over chars, but they do have disadvantages in readability and typeability. Thus:

**Answer: Use chars. Set the `double_quotes` flag explicity.**

Comment: That ... makes sense. SWI-Prolog's opinion about the "traditional" way of a list interpretation of a double-quoted element is that it is a list of codes: [double_quotes flag](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_prolog_flag/2#flag:double_quotes). _If `--traditional` (command line option) is given, the default is `codes`, which produces a list of character codes, integers that represent a Unicode code-point. The value `chars` produces a list of one-character atoms and the value `atom` makes double quotes the same as single quotes (excpt for escaping), creating a atom._

Comment: When you define a DCG rule, you can use double quoted literals in every Prolog I know of, including SWI-Prolog, without mucking around with any global flags. Your observations might be correct, but your conclusions are questionable. The bold **Answer** at the end is at best an opinion.

Comment: Yes you can use double quoted literals in a DCG rule, but you have no guarantee that they will mean what you want. If you define `foo --> "foo".`, should `phrase(foo, [f, o, o]).` succeed? The Prolog standard doesn't tell you. But it does give you the flag you can tweak to decide for yourself.

Comment: *you can't even know that the double quoted list is actually a list* that is incorrect. The default value for the flag `double_quotes` is **implementation defined**. So you do know what `"abc"` means prior to changing the flag. You need to read the accompanying documentation first. That holds also for many other aspects. Like the supported processor character set, or the kind of integers supported etc.

Answer (score 4):

I should start to by noting that the answer to the *"Should text-processing DCGs be written to handle codes or chars? Or both?"* question can be **neither**. DCGs work by using an implicit difference list to thread state. But the elements of that difference list can be other than chars or codes. It depends on the output of text tokenization and what exactly *text processing* entails. E.g. I have worked on and come across Prolog NLP applications where codes/chars were only used for the basic tokenization and the reasoning was performed (still with DCGS) using either atoms or compound terms that reified the token data (e.g. `v(Verb)` or `n(Noun)`). One of those applications (a personal assistant like it's common nowadays in phones) used atoms produced by a voice-recognition component.

But let's go back to *chars* vs *codes*. Legacy practices and failed standardization left Prolog with problematic text representation. ASCII  gives us a singe quote, a back quote, and a double-quote. With single quotes being used for atoms, a choice could have been made to use e.g. back quotes for representing a list of codes and double-quotes for representing a list of chars. Or the other way around. Instead, and this is where standardization failed, we got the problematic `double_quotes` flag. There's no shortage of Prolog code in the wild that makes an assumption about the meaning of double-quoted terms and thus works or breaks depending on the implicit value of the `double_quotes` flag (if you think this is mainly  an issue with legacy code, think again). Guess what happens when we try to combine code that require different values for the flag? Note that, in almost all systems (including those that support modules), the flag value is **global** ... As Isabelle wrote in her answer, setting the flag explicitly is good general advice. But not, as I explained, without problems.

Some systems provide additional values for the flag. E.g. SWI-Prolog allows the flag to also be set to `string`. GNU Prolog supports additional `atom_no_escape`, `chars_no_escape` and `codes_no_escape`. Some systems only support `codes`. Some systems also provide a `back_quotes` flag. This Babel tower means that *portable* and *resilient* code is often forced to use atoms to represent text. But this is may not be ideal from a performance perspective.

Back to the original question. As Isabelle mentioned, `chars` is usually a more readable (read, easier to debug) choice. But, depending on the Prolog system, `codes` may provide better performance. If application performance is critical, benchmark both solutions. Some recent Prolog systems (e.g. Scryer-Prolog or Trealla Prolog) have efficient support for `chars`. Older systems may trail behind.

Answer (score 4):

Note that your question is very much related to I/O. Prior to ISO, many systems in the DEC-10 succession supported a single kind of I/O via `get0/1` and `put/1` (and versions for `tty`) which served both characters and bytes **at the same time**. What can go wrong with that? Today, that is obvious. But multi-octet character set handling ([MOCSH](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/#MOCSH) as it was called) was for many a much more exotic feature as it is today, a quarter century after the standard's publication. After all, the today mostly accepted UTF-8 encoding was *invented* 1992-09 and first published in 1993. And like so many projects like TRON it could have failed as well. Some other programming languages got burnt by betting on UCS-2/UTF-16 encoding.

What the standard did was to split I/O into character and byte I/O (and their corresponding types `text` and `binary`). So there is now `get_char/1`, `get_byte/1` ... That the `_byte` versions all use integers in the range of 0..255 was non-controversial (plus -1 for EOF). But what about the `_char` versions? The only way to resolve this was to provide both `_char` and `_code` versions and consequently `chars` and `codes` versions of double-quoted strings and related built-ins.  The default for flag `double_quotes` is implementation defined (7.11.2.5).

In this manner systems with a lot of DEC-10 legacy could continue to use codes explicitly. For them, an integer thus meant either an integer or a byte or a character. But users of such system still could use the better encoding. New systems that do not have to deal with such legacies going back to 1977 opt as default for `chars` like Tau, Scryer, and Trealla. As much as tradition is concerned, note that [Prolog I](http://alain.colmerauer.free.fr/alcol/ArchivesPublications/ManuelProlog/Pr.pdf), often called Marseille Prolog, did encode double quoted strings as lists of atoms of length one. And in the preliminary version of Prolog of 1972, often called Prolog 0, strings were encoded as `nil-s-t-r-i-n-g` qua `boum` facilitating stemming. In any case, not a single character code was present at all.

The advantages of `chars` should be obvious. It is much easier to read and debug, in particular if you have partially instantiated strings, say `[a,X,c]` vs. `[97,X,99]`, which occur often when generalizing queries as with [`library(diadem)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/diadem.pl). It is also a bit shorter to write. And, double quoted strings can be used [for printing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868).

**If** you really want to write programs that both support `codes` and `chars` at the same time, use rather goals like `[Ch] = "a"` where `Ch` is now the atom `a` or the integer 97 or 129 or whatever processor character set you are using. It all depends on the Prolog flag `double_quotes`. And more succinctly you can write

```
nonzero(C) --> [C],{member(C,"123456789")}.
```

What is even more important is that `phrase("abc", "abc")` still holds.

However, changing that flag within the same application is certainly not a good idea (nor to switch to the value `atom` or some non-conforming value).

((When using `chars` note that single quotes as in `C = 'a'` are a bit misleading since the single quotes do not serve any purpose. Instead, round brackets are preferable if you want to ensure that the code will be valid even in the presence of an operator declaration for `a`. When `a` occurs as a functor's argument or a list's element, no round brackets are needed, but they are often used redundantly in operator declarations.))

Comment: Thank you. That is the first time I hear someone mention [TRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRON_project). I always thought it disappeared due to lack of interest but apparently it didn't disappear and got the Huawei treatement from our USian friends.

Comment: See the [MOCSH](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/#MOCSH) link for more on all this.

Answer (score 1):

You are making incorrect assumptions. These are not "chars":

```
foo_or_bar(foo) --> "foo".
```

The `"foo"` is a string, in SWI-Prolog, but this works perfectly *within a DCG rule definition*. The place to read about this is [here](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-dquotes-port), in particular:

> **A DCG literal**
>
> Although represented as a list of codes is the correct representation for handling in DCGs, the DCG translator can recognise the literal and convert it to the proper representation. Such code need not be modified.

All your other suggestions are just unnecessary, you should be either enumerating explicitly all possible "nonzeros", digits and so on, or using the library.

PS: if your main goal is to write code that runs on any Prolog, you might as well use something like Logtalk instead.

Comment: I have to disagree. I know these are not chars, and `"foo"` inside of a DCG is not an SWi-Prolog string, it is a list of codes. The text quoted says as much. See also the note at the end of my question. Also, Logtalk is not Prolog (though I will certainly look into it)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer you say, "and "foo" inside of a DCG is not an SWi-Prolog string, it is a list of codes." I don't want to argue about this, it seems clear enough to me. It is a string but the term expansion of SWI-Prolog handles is so that DCGs using double-quoted literals don't have to be re-written. Please re-read the quoted text and check out the SWI-Prolog DCG expansion source code if you don't believe me.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Logtalk is not Prolog, but it is the only mature project that offers a compatibility layer between different Prolog implementations. So if you don't want to commit to an implementation, Logtalk is a pragmatic choice.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer as a rule of thumb, reading and listening carefully is more useful than writing and talking. I will follow my own advice and abandon this thread, since it is too full of opinion and I don't see any chance at salvaging it at this point. I did what I could to point out factual errors, but this isn't helping, apparently.

Comment: "any chance at salvaging it at this point". Are you serious. This is a good thread.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer :-) no, just joking

Comment: @DavidTonhofer but seriously, figure out what your goal is. If you want to define DCGs, use double-quoted literals and forget about what they really are.