# In which programming languages is the single quote indispensable?

Tags: programming-languages, quotation-marks

In several languages, one can forgo single quotation marks `'` completely.
For example in Python, single quotation marks can always be replaced with double quotation marks

```
'string' == "string"
```

In Ruby, single quotation marks can be used to encode raw strings; but one can alternatively use another syntax:

```
'string' == %q(string)
```

**Question**: in which programming languages do single quotation marks `'` play a unique role that cannot be replaced?

**The same question put differently**: in which programming languages does one get handicapped if their single quotation mark `'` key is broken?

Comment: SQL requires single quotation marks to delineate strings and column names with spaces.

Comment: [List generating questions aren't suitable for SO.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/19068)

Comment: @Quentin Would you have in mind a better place for this question?

Comment: No, I wouldn't. (Which is not to say that it is OK to ask it here because I'm not suggesting a better place).

Answer (score 1):

No difference between `'` and `"`: python, node.js

Difference between `'` and `"`: c, c++, c#, go, prolog, ruby, bash, SQL, java

In C, C++, C#, Go you can replace `'a'` with `"a"[0]`

In java you can do `"a".charAt(0)`

In ruby and bash the difference is interpolation, so you need to use `"` instead of `'`, but you need to escape special signs.

The difference in Prolog is depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264699/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-prolog)

Answer (score 1):

Pascal and derivatives use single quotes to denote strings, while double quotes have no special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Java can be written entirely in UTF-16 escape sequences which are interpreted before compilation, so you could replace any `'` with `\u0027`.