# Marquee in Prolog

Tags: prolog, marquee

Well known from [html](/questions/tagged/html), [marquee](/questions/tagged/marquee) is clearly the pinnacle of the Semantic Web.  Or rather its nadir side by side with the blink tag. In any case, how can we represent marquee in Prolog? In other words, how to define a relation `marquee/2` such that the following holds:

```
?- marquee("Prolog is marquee ready! ",M).
   M = "Prolog is marquee ready! "
;  M = "rolog is marquee ready! P"
;  M = "olog is marquee ready! Pr"
;  M = "log is marquee ready! Pro"
;  M = "og is marquee ready! Prol"
;  M = "g is marquee ready! Prolo"
;  M = " is marquee ready! Prolog"
;  M = "is marquee ready! Prolog "
;  M = "s marquee ready! Prolog i"
;  M = " marquee ready! Prolog is"
;  M = "marquee ready! Prolog is "
;  ... .
?- M=[m|_],marquee("Prolog is marquee ready! ",M).
   M = "marquee ready! Prolog is "
;  M = "marquee ready! Prolog is "
;  M = "marquee ready! Prolog is " % infinitely many redundant answers
;  ... .
```

So how can I define `marquee/2` in [ISO Prolog](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#status_quo) just using the [Prolog prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#prologue)? The double quotes above assume [`set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868), and the answer write option `max_depth(0)` needs to be set to get the entire string.

What I have tried is [`member/2`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#member) but it only describes the characters and then I tried [`nth0/3` and `nth1/3`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#nth0) but they only described two characters in sequence as in:

```
?- T = "Prolog is marquee ready! ", nth1(I,T,A),nth0(I,T,B).
   T = "Prolog is marquee ready! ", I = 1, A = 'P', B = r
;  T = "Prolog is marquee ready! ", I = 2, A = r, B = o
;  ... .
```

Edit: one clarification about the repetitions. They should fit together seamlessly, as in

```
?- marquee("! ",M).
   M = "! "
;  M = " !"
;  M = "! "
;  M = " !"
;  M = "! "
;  M = " !"
;  M = "! "
;  M = " !"
;  M = "! "
;  M = " !"
;  ... .
```

Comment: Do you prefer something usable as a single query (without any—possibly recursive—auxiliary predicates) or is that just as good as long as it is short?

Comment: Just a definition for `marquee/2`as small as possible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, hat tip to [this answer and the author, @brebs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077627/4609915).

I looked at `marquee_/3` ... and `append/3` looked back at me—with shuffled arguments.

So here's the minimally updated version of `marquee/2`:

```
marquee(L,M) :-
   append(L,R,LD),
   append(R,M,LD).   % was: marquee_(LD,R,M)
```

Sample queries:

```
?- marquee("prolog",Xs).
   Xs = "prolog"
;  Xs = "rologp"
;  Xs = "ologpr"
;  Xs = "logpro"
;  Xs = "ogprol"
;  Xs = "gprolo"
;  Xs = "prolog"
;  Xs = "rologp"
;  ... .

?- marquee("",Xs).
   Xs = []
;  Xs = []
;  ... .
```

Comment: How/why does this guarantee the right order or results?

Comment: @ScottHunter. The definition of `append/3` gives us this order. For some illustration, consider the query `?- append(A,Xs,['P',r,o,l,o,g|A]).` To me, this shows the magic of unification:)

Answer (score 5):

this is an alternative solution (updated after a suggestion in the comments), hope this solves the task

```
marquee(String,String).
marquee([H|T],R):-
    append(T,[H],NewEl),
    marquee(NewEl,R).


?- marquee("Prolog is marquee ready! ", M).
M = ['P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' '];
M = [r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P'];
...

?- M=[m|_],marquee("Prolog is marquee ready! ",M).
M = [m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' '];
M = [m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' '];
...
```

Comment: Perfect! Yet, its size ... And what is the purpose of the goal `nth0(0,[H|T],E1)`?

Comment: Absolutely useless. I've updated my answer

Comment: I said perfect, but then `?- marquee(non_marqueeable, M). M = non_marqueeable.`

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure this satisfy all your requisites, hope so

```
marquee(Ls, M):- 
    length(Ls, Len), 
    Max is Len-1,
    between(0, Max, Roll),
    roll(Ls, M, Roll).

lis_pos_elem(Lis, Pos, Elem) :- nth1(Pos, Lis, Elem).

new_index(Shift, Max, I1, I2):-
    I is I1 - Shift,
    ( 
        I < 1,
        I2 is Max + I
    ;
        I2 = I
    ), !.

roll(L,L,0).
roll(L1,L2,R):-
    R > 0,
    length(L1, Len),
    numlist(1, Len, Index),
    maplist(new_index(R, Len), Index, ShiftedIndexes), 
    maplist(lis_pos_elem(L1), ShiftedIndexes, L2).
```

```
?-
marquee("Prolog is marquee ready! ", M); true.
M = ['P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' '] ;
M = [' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !] ;
M = [!, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y] ;
M = [y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d] ;
M = [d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a] ;
M = [a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e] ;
M = [e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r] ;
M = [r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' '] ;
M = [' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e] ;
M = [e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e] ;
M = [e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u] ;
M = [u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q] ;
M = [q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r] ;
M = [r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a] ;
M = [a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m] ;
M = [m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' '] ;
M = [' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s] ;
M = [s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i] ;
M = [i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g, ' '] ;
M = [' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o, g] ;
M = [g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l, o] ;
M = [o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o, l] ;
M = [l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r, o] ;
M = [o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P', r] ;
M = [r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', m, a, r, q, u, e, e, ' ', r, e, a, d, y, !, ' ', 'P'] ;
true.
```

Comment: This is a good start! But the idea is that it produces infinitely many such solutions. Also, maybe you could reduce (in another answer) the size of the program significantly.

Comment: ... just one thing is that you use `numlist/3` which is not part of the Prolog prologue.

Comment: And now I see answers are enumerated in the other direction.

Answer (score 3):

This feels fairly intuitive, but not super-short:

```
marquee(L, M) :-
    % Convert to List-Remainder difference list
    append(L, R, LD),
    marquee_(LD, R, M).

marquee_(M, [], M).
% Move from head to tail
marquee_([H|T], [H|R], M) :-
    marquee_(T, R, M).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- marquee([a,b,c,d], L).
L = [a, b, c, d] ;
L = [b, c, d, a] ;
L = [c, d, a, b] ;
L = [d, a, b, c] ;
L = [a, b, c, d] ;
L = [b, c, d, a] ;
...
```

I suspect there's a trick to convert that into a short DCG that I'm missing...

Comment: Just one rule necessary....

Comment: Also, why do you exclude the empty list?

Comment: Updated to prevent excluding empty list.

Comment: While nice, it could be much shorter. Please try in another answer!

Comment: *I suspect there's a trick*: you are soo close! No DCG, just...

Comment: I was thinking that there was `phrase/3` involved next, rather than another `append` :-)

Comment: You could always replace a goal `append(A,B,C)` by `phrase(seq(A),C,B)`. And (with a lot of pain...) you could replace the first `append(L,R,LD)` by `phrase(L,LD,R)` although that really hurts (as it includes now many unwanted solutions...)

Answer (score 1):

This is my updated answer:

```
marquee_right(S0, M):- 
    length(S0, Len),
    length(_, Roll), 
    Shift is Len - (Roll mod Len),
    length(P1, Shift),
    append(P1, P2, S0),
    append(P2, P1, M).

marquee_left(S0, M):- 
    length(S0, Len),
    length(_, Roll), 
    Shift is Roll mod Len,
    length(P1, Shift),
    append(P1, P2, S0),
    append(P2, P1, M).
```

@damianodamiano [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77065750/20160345) seems really good and declarative, maybe my answer follow more a procedural style.
Comments and notes are appreciated.

Comment: Oh, better rename `marquee_left/2`... Otherwise flawless as to its declarative nature. Still, the size ... six goals. Can't you narrow it down?

Answer (score 1):

Rolling rolling rolling ...

```
marquee([],[]) :- repeat, true.
marquee([H|T],X) :- m(T,R,[H|R],X).
m([H|T],[H|R],Y,X) :- m(T,R,Y,X).
m([],[],Y,Y).
m([],[H|Z],[H|R],X) :- m([],Z,R,X).
```

Testing:

```
8 ?- marquee([],X).
X = [] ;
X = [] ;
X = [] ;
X = [] ;
X = [] ;
X = [] 
......

9 ?- marquee([1,2,3,4],X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
X = [2, 3, 4, 1] ;
X = [3, 4, 1, 2] ;
X = [4, 1, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
X = [2, 3, 4, 1] ;
X = [3, 4, 1, 2] ;
X = [4, 1, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
X = [2, 3, 4, 1] ;
X = [3, 4, 1, 2] ;
X = [4, 1, 2, 3] 
......
```

Comment: Nice, but quite large.